# Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary where keys are strings, and values are integers.

```
stats = {'a': 1, 'b': 3000, 'c': 0}
```

How do I get the key with the maximum value? In this case, it is `'b'`.

---

Is there a nicer approach than using an intermediate list with reversed key-value tuples?

```
inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in stats.items()]
print(max(inverse)[1])
```

Comment: Um, what's wrong with `max(stats)`?

Comment: `max(stats)` will use the labels as keys (it will return `'c'`, given that's the maximum label), `max(stats, key=lambda key: stats[key])` is what OP was after (which will return `'b'`, label of maximal indexed value). Is it any clearer?

Comment: This inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in stats.items()]
print(max(inverse)[1]) has a limitation that it will only return one key when there are maximum value duplicates. For example, stats = {'a': 1, 'b': 3000, 'c': 3000} will only return 'c' if the requirement is to return ['b','c']

Answer (score 772, accepted):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` for that:

```
import operator
stats = {'a': 1000, 'b': 3000, 'c': 100}
max(stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

And instead of building a new list in memory use `stats.iteritems()`. The `key` parameter to the `max()` function is a function that computes a key that is used to determine how to rank items.

Please note that if you were to have another key-value pair 'd': 3000 that this method will only return **one** of the **two** even though they both have the maximum value.

```
>>> import operator
>>> stats = {'a': 1000, 'b': 3000, 'c': 100, 'd': 3000}
>>> max(stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
'b'
```

If using Python3:

```
>>> max(stats.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
'b'
```

Comment: Even cleaner, I think= `max(stats.iterkeys(), key=(lambda key: stats[key]))`

Comment: Why not just use `key=lambda x: x[1]`?

Comment: in python 3 @Lucretiel's (correctly spelled) solution fails. it should be: max(stats.keys(), key=(lambda k: stats[k])) since keys() now does what iterkeys() used to do automatically.

Comment: Rigth you are. Interestingly, a solution that's exactly as memory efficient and works in both Python 2 and 3 is: `max(stats, key=lambda key: stats[key])`

Comment: Honestly I think that the comments have the cleaner and better solution.

Comment: `max(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]` for python3.

Comment: I'm getting the following exception trying this: 'int' object is not callable
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100, 'd':3000}
print(max(stats, key=lambda key: stats[key]))

Comment: @BenDundee: Using a lambda instead of operator.itemgetter is significantly slower, but functionally equivalent.

Comment: `this method will only return one of the two` Is it randomly selected? What's the criteria?

Comment: For type collections.Counter() - use -                                                     `max(stats.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]`

Answer (score 2006):

```
max(stats, key=stats.get)
```

Comment: if you really wanted to do it this way you could do `stats[max(stats, key=stats.get)]`

Comment: @scottmrogowski, ss.  It provides the key with the maximum value, as asked.  The max value would be simply max(stats.values()).

Comment: This should be the answer as it is the simplest and was exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Coady what if there is a tie between two keys (with the same value)? I want to get them both, but I get only one.

Comment: @oba2311 `max_value = max(stats.values());  {key for key, value in stats.items() if value == max_value}`

Comment: Why not just `max(stats)` ?

Comment: @ElliottB: `max(stats)` returns max of keys, not the key where its value is max.

Comment: @oba2311 - you can get all the keys with maximum value using - 
`max_val = [keys for keys,values in stats.items() if values == max(stats.values())]`

Comment: This is the best answer as it is the simplest and does not involve importing another library. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This will break when stats is an empty dictionary. For a robust solution, we can go with `max(stats, key=stats.get) if stats else None`

Comment: @A.Coady I get how this works but I'm confused how stats.get doesn't throw an error. When I lookup the get function it says it's required to have a key value. Can you explain?

Comment: BY FAR this is the best answer, no doubts. I just have a question, I know it works, but why? How to interpret this simple line: `max(stats, key=stats.get)`? Why is function `get` used as the key? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: @Bhindi If the dictionary can be empty, and one doesn't want to deal with exception handling, then `max(stats, key=stats.get, default=None)` is simpler than using `if...else` (assuming `None` is not a possible key).

Comment: @NickS1 Perhaps refer to the docs for [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: I had to use `__getitem__` instead of `get` to calm the type-checking linters

Answer (score 269):

I have tested MANY variants, and this is the fastest way to return the key of dict with the max value:

```
def keywithmaxval(d):
     """ a) create a list of the dict's keys and values; 
         b) return the key with the max value"""  
     v = list(d.values())
     k = list(d.keys())
     return k[v.index(max(v))]
```

To give you an idea, here are some candidate methods:

```
def f1():  
     v = list(d1.values())
     k = list(d1.keys())
     return k[v.index(max(v))]
    
def f2():
    d3 = {v: k for k,v in d1.items()}
    return d3[max(d3)]
    
def f3():
    return list(filter(lambda t: t[1] == max(d1.values()), d1.items()))[0][0]    
    
def f3b():
    # same as f3 but remove the call to max from the lambda
    m = max(d1.values())
    return list(filter(lambda t: t[1] == m, d1.items()))[0][0]        
    
def f4():
    return [k for k, v in d1.items() if v == max(d1.values())][0]    
    
def f4b():
    # same as f4 but remove the max from the comprehension
    m = max(d1.values())
    return [k for k,v in d1.items() if v == m][0]        
    
def f5():
    return max(d1.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]    
    
def f6():
    return max(d1, key=d1.get)     
    
def f7():
     """ a) create a list of the dict's keys and values; 
         b) return the key with the max value"""    
     v = list(d1.values())
     return list(d1.keys())[v.index(max(v))]    
     
def f8():
     return max(d1, key=lambda k: d1[k])     
     
tl = [f1, f2, f3b, f4b, f5, f6, f7, f8, f4, f3]     
cmpthese.cmpthese(tl, c=100)
```

The test dictionary:

```
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 8, 4: 3, 5: 6, 6: 9, 7: 17, 8: 4, 9: 20, 10: 7, 11: 15, 
    12: 10, 13: 10, 14: 18, 15: 18, 16: 5, 17: 13, 18: 21, 19: 21, 20: 8, 
    21: 8, 22: 16, 23: 16, 24: 11, 25: 24, 26: 11, 27: 112, 28: 19, 29: 19, 
    30: 19, 3077: 36, 32: 6, 33: 27, 34: 14, 35: 14, 36: 22, 4102: 39, 38: 22, 
    39: 35, 40: 9, 41: 110, 42: 9, 43: 30, 44: 17, 45: 17, 46: 17, 47: 105, 48: 12, 
    49: 25, 50: 25, 51: 25, 52: 12, 53: 12, 54: 113, 1079: 50, 56: 20, 57: 33, 
    58: 20, 59: 33, 60: 20, 61: 20, 62: 108, 63: 108, 64: 7, 65: 28, 66: 28, 67: 28, 
    68: 15, 69: 15, 70: 15, 71: 103, 72: 23, 73: 116, 74: 23, 75: 15, 76: 23, 77: 23, 
    78: 36, 79: 36, 80: 10, 81: 23, 82: 111, 83: 111, 84: 10, 85: 10, 86: 31, 87: 31, 
    88: 18, 89: 31, 90: 18, 91: 93, 92: 18, 93: 18, 94: 106, 95: 106, 96: 13, 9232: 35, 
    98: 26, 99: 26, 100: 26, 101: 26, 103: 88, 104: 13, 106: 13, 107: 101, 1132: 63, 
    2158: 51, 112: 21, 113: 13, 116: 21, 118: 34, 119: 34, 7288: 45, 121: 96, 122: 21, 
    124: 109, 125: 109, 128: 8, 1154: 32, 131: 29, 134: 29, 136: 16, 137: 91, 140: 16, 
    142: 104, 143: 104, 146: 117, 148: 24, 149: 24, 152: 24, 154: 24, 155: 86, 160: 11, 
    161: 99, 1186: 76, 3238: 49, 167: 68, 170: 11, 172: 32, 175: 81, 178: 32, 179: 32, 
    182: 94, 184: 19, 31: 107, 188: 107, 190: 107, 196: 27, 197: 27, 202: 27, 206: 89, 
    208: 14, 214: 102, 215: 102, 220: 115, 37: 22, 224: 22, 226: 14, 232: 22, 233: 84, 
    238: 35, 242: 97, 244: 22, 250: 110, 251: 66, 1276: 58, 256: 9, 2308: 33, 262: 30, 
    263: 79, 268: 30, 269: 30, 274: 92, 1300: 27, 280: 17, 283: 61, 286: 105, 292: 118, 
    296: 25, 298: 25, 304: 25, 310: 87, 1336: 71, 319: 56, 322: 100, 323: 100, 325: 25, 
    55: 113, 334: 69, 340: 12, 1367: 40, 350: 82, 358: 33, 364: 95, 376: 108, 
    377: 64, 2429: 46, 394: 28, 395: 77, 404: 28, 412: 90, 1438: 53, 425: 59, 430: 103, 
    1456: 97, 433: 28, 445: 72, 448: 23, 466: 85, 479: 54, 484: 98, 485: 98, 488: 23, 
    6154: 37, 502: 67, 4616: 34, 526: 80, 538: 31, 566: 62, 3644: 44, 577: 31, 97: 119, 
    592: 26, 593: 75, 1619: 48, 638: 57, 646: 101, 650: 26, 110: 114, 668: 70, 2734: 41, 
    700: 83, 1732: 30, 719: 52, 728: 96, 754: 65, 1780: 74, 4858: 47, 130: 29, 790: 78, 
    1822: 43, 2051: 38, 808: 29, 850: 60, 866: 29, 890: 73, 911: 42, 958: 55, 970: 99, 
    976: 24, 166: 112}
```

And the test results under Python 3.2:

```
    rate/sec       f4      f3    f3b     f8     f5     f2    f4b     f6     f7     f1
f4       454       --   -2.5% -96.9% -97.5% -98.6% -98.6% -98.7% -98.7% -98.9% -99.0%
f3       466     2.6%      -- -96.8% -97.4% -98.6% -98.6% -98.6% -98.7% -98.9% -99.0%
f3b   14,715  3138.9% 3057.4%     -- -18.6% -55.5% -56.0% -56.4% -58.3% -63.8% -68.4%
f8    18,070  3877.3% 3777.3%  22.8%     -- -45.4% -45.9% -46.5% -48.8% -55.5% -61.2%
f5    33,091  7183.7% 7000.5% 124.9%  83.1%     --  -1.0%  -2.0%  -6.3% -18.6% -29.0%
f2    33,423  7256.8% 7071.8% 127.1%  85.0%   1.0%     --  -1.0%  -5.3% -17.7% -28.3%
f4b   33,762  7331.4% 7144.6% 129.4%  86.8%   2.0%   1.0%     --  -4.4% -16.9% -27.5%
f6    35,300  7669.8% 7474.4% 139.9%  95.4%   6.7%   5.6%   4.6%     -- -13.1% -24.2%
f7    40,631  8843.2% 8618.3% 176.1% 124.9%  22.8%  21.6%  20.3%  15.1%     -- -12.8%
f1    46,598 10156.7% 9898.8% 216.7% 157.9%  40.8%  39.4%  38.0%  32.0%  14.7%     --
```

And under Python 2.7:

```
    rate/sec       f3       f4     f8    f3b     f6     f5     f2    f4b     f7     f1
f3       384       --    -2.6% -97.1% -97.2% -97.9% -97.9% -98.0% -98.2% -98.5% -99.2%
f4       394     2.6%       -- -97.0% -97.2% -97.8% -97.9% -98.0% -98.1% -98.5% -99.1%
f8    13,079  3303.3%  3216.1%     --  -5.6% -28.6% -29.9% -32.8% -38.3% -49.7% -71.2%
f3b   13,852  3504.5%  3412.1%   5.9%     -- -24.4% -25.8% -28.9% -34.6% -46.7% -69.5%
f6    18,325  4668.4%  4546.2%  40.1%  32.3%     --  -1.8%  -5.9% -13.5% -29.5% -59.6%
f5    18,664  4756.5%  4632.0%  42.7%  34.7%   1.8%     --  -4.1% -11.9% -28.2% -58.8%
f2    19,470  4966.4%  4836.5%  48.9%  40.6%   6.2%   4.3%     --  -8.1% -25.1% -57.1%
f4b   21,187  5413.0%  5271.7%  62.0%  52.9%  15.6%  13.5%   8.8%     -- -18.5% -53.3%
f7    26,002  6665.8%  6492.4%  98.8%  87.7%  41.9%  39.3%  33.5%  22.7%     -- -42.7%
f1    45,354 11701.5% 11399.0% 246.8% 227.4% 147.5% 143.0% 132.9% 114.1%  74.4%     --
```

You can see that `f1` is the fastest under Python 3.2 and 2.7 (or, more completely, `keywithmaxval` at the top of this post)

Comment: This seems fishy. `f7` is like `f1`, just not giving a name to an intermediate object. `f7` should be (very slightly) faster than `f1`, not **much** slower. And that's what I get: `>>> timeit.timeit("f1()","from __main__ import f1, f7, d1", number=10000)
0.26785888786807277
>>> timeit.timeit("f7()","from __main__ import f1, f7, d1", number=10000)
0.26770628307832567`

Comment: agree f1 is like f7. Did test with ipython %timeit and both came with same performance on my machine on python 2.7.  Testing: f1 - 
18 µs per loop
Testing: f2 - 
33.7 µs per loop
Testing: f3b - 
50 µs per loop
Testing: f4b - 
30.7 µs per loop
Testing: f5 - 
28 µs per loop
Testing: f6 - 
23 µs per loop
Testing: f7 - 
18 µs per loop
Testing: f8 - 
43.9 µs per loop
Testing: f4 - 
2.16 ms per loop
Testing: f3 - 
2.29 ms per loop

Comment: f1 is also applicable wherever max(d, key) is not available.

Comment: I thought dict is unsorted, couldn't d.keys and d.values theoretically be ordered differently?

Comment: The list-copy solutions are smelly to me. How's the performance on a dict with thousands or millions of entries?

Comment: @the_wolf, I understand that tuples are faster than lists in Python (this is one of their advantages)

Comment: @Dimath you are right. That's what happening to me.

Comment: doesn't matter. they're all O(nlogn)

Comment: @DonaldAllen But some are O(n) :)

Comment: I got a similar result when comparing methods to [find the index of the maximum in a Pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741928/1609514). The python index method was the fastest (although my test was on a small series).

Answer (score 142):

You can use:

```
max(d, key=d.get) 
# which is equivalent to 
max(d, key=lambda k: d.get(k))
```

To return the key-value pair use:

```
max(d.items(), key=lambda k: k[1])
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's much simpler than using operator

Comment: What is the time complexity of this?

Comment: By far the best, answer:  For explanation the `d.items()` creates a tuple and the lambda function  uses a the value of the tuple as the object to evaluate, instead of the key.

Comment: @music2177 `max()` is *O(n)* and dict lookups are *O(1)* on average, so *O(n)*.

Comment: I had to use `__getitem__` instead of `get` to calm the type-checking linters

Answer (score 82):

If you need to know only a key with the max value you can do it without `iterkeys` or `iteritems` because iteration through dictionary in Python is iteration through it's keys.

```
max_key = max(stats, key=lambda k: stats[k])
```

**EDIT:**

*From comments, @user1274878 :*

> I am new to python. Can you please explain your answer in steps?

Yep...

#### max

> max(iterable[, key])
>
> max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
>
> Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments.

The optional `key` argument describes how to compare elements to get maximum among them:

```
lambda <item>: return <a result of operation with item>
```

Returned values will be compared.

#### Dict

Python dict is a hash table. A key of dict is a hash of an object declared as a key. Due to performance reasons iteration though a dict implemented as iteration through it's keys.

Therefore we can use it to rid operation of obtaining a keys list.

#### Closure

> A function defined inside another function is called a nested function. Nested functions can access variables of the enclosing scope.

The `stats` variable available through `__closure__` attribute of the `lambda` function as a pointer to the value of the variable defined in the parent scope.

Comment: @I159: I am new to python. Can you please explain your answer in steps

Answer (score 75):

Example:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
```

if you wanna find the max value with its key, maybe follwing could be simple, without any relevant functions.

```
max(stats, key=stats.get)
```

the output is the key which has the max value.

Comment: this solution tested faster than
max(stats, key=lambda key: stats[key])

Answer (score 53):

Here is another one:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
max(stats.iterkeys(), key=lambda k: stats[k])
```

The function `key` simply returns the value that should be used for ranking and `max()` returns the demanded element right away.

Comment: .iterkeys is not needed in your answer (it's the default when iterating a dict). However, note that the .iteritems method fetches both key and value in one step, so there is no need for an extra __getitem__ per key as needed with .iterkeys.

Comment: This is a great answer because it is very clear what's going on and is thus easy to extend to other situations.

Comment: in python3 version: `max(stats, key=lambda k: stats[k])`

Answer (score 43):

```
key, value = max(stats.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

If you don't care about value (I'd be surprised, but) you can do:

```
key, _ = max(stats.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

I like the tuple unpacking better than a [0] subscript at the end of the expression.
I never like the readability of lambda expressions very much, but find this one better than the operator.itemgetter(1) IMHO.

Answer (score 36):

```py
max(stats, key=stats.get, default=None)
```

If `stats` could be an empty dictionary, using only `max(stats, key=stats.get)` will otherwise raise `ValueError`.

This answer is safe to use so long as `None` is not a possible key in the dictionary.

Comment: Any idea what the time complexity of this is?

Comment: @RaGe Time complexity is  O(n)

Comment: @Bhindi how did you know that time complexity of this is O(n)?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi: You can verify the time complexity of max() function from here - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: what is the stats.get do ? It returns 'built-in method get of dict object at 0x7ff06ed0fa40'

Comment: @IndianGrandma007: It returns 'built-in method get of dict stats

Comment: **Don't use this!** Think about what would happen if `None` were a key in `stats`: you wouldn't be able to tell the correct answer from the "error" answer. Instead, use try-except, for example: `try: res = max(stats, key=stats.get); except ValueError: print("Empty dict. No max."); else: print("Max:", res)`

Comment: Edit your answer to use `max(stats, key=stats.get, default=None)` instead.

Answer (score 35):

Given that more than one entry my have the max value. I would make a list of the keys that have the max value as their value.

```
>>> stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100, 'd':3000}
>>> [key for m in [max(stats.values())] for key,val in stats.iteritems() if val == m]
['b', 'd']
```

This will give you 'b' and any other max key as well.

Note: For python 3 use `stats.items()` instead of `stats.iteritems()`

Comment: Your solution is OK but computes the maximum value as many times as there are items in the dict. If computing `max` were expensive (e.g., a LONG dictionary) I'd recommend `[key for m in [max(stats.values())] for key,val in stats.iteritems() if val == m]` if you want an one-liner, otherwise compute `m = ...` beforehand.

Comment: Just a short note: For python 3 use stats.items() instead of stats.iteritems().

Answer (score 26):

To get the maximum key/value of the dictionary `stats`:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
```

- Based on **keys**

`>>> max(stats.items(), key = lambda x: x[0])
('c', 100)`

- Based on **values**

`>>> max(stats.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
('b', 3000)`

Of course, if you want to get only the key or value from the result, you can use tuple indexing. For Example, to get the key corresponding to the maximum value:

`>>> max(stats.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
'b'`

**Explanation**

The dictionary method [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) in Python 3 returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) of the dictionary. When this view object is iterated over, by the `max` function, it yields the dictionary items as tuples of the form `(key, value)`.

`>>> list(stats.items())
[('c', 100), ('b', 3000), ('a', 1000)]`

When you use the [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression `lambda x: x[1]`, in each iteration, `x`  is one of these tuples `(key, value)`. So, by choosing the right index, you select whether you want to compare by keys or by values.

**Python 2**

For Python 2.2+ releases, the same code will work. However, it is better to use [`iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) dictionary method instead of [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) for performance.

**Notes**

- This answer is based on the comments on [Climbs_lika_Spyder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268285/1802750).
- The used code was tested on Python 3.5.2 and Python 2.7.10 .

Answer (score 20):

```
d = {'A': 4,'B':10}

min_v = min(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))
# min_v is (4,'A')

max_v = max(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))
# max_v is (10,'B')
```

Answer (score 16):

I was not satisfied with any of these answers. `max` always picks the first key with the max value. The dictionary could have multiple keys with that value.

```
def keys_with_top_values(my_dict):
    return [key  for (key, value) in my_dict.items() if value == max(my_dict.values())]
```

Posting this answer in case it helps someone out.
See the below SO post

[Which maximum does Python pick in the case of a tie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783000/which-maximum-does-python-pick-in-the-case-of-a-tie)

Comment: This solution returns all the keys with the max value.  
max(stats, key=stats.get) only returns the first key it finds.

Answer (score 13):

Per the iterated solutions via comments in the selected answer...

In Python 3:

```
max(stats.keys(), key=(lambda k: stats[k]))
```

In Python 2:

```
max(stats.iterkeys(), key=(lambda k: stats[k]))
```

Comment: Your solution for Python 3 also works for Python 2.7.

Comment: because keys() does not return an iterator in python 2 and hence takes a performance hit

Answer (score 12):

With `collections.Counter` you could do

```
>>> import collections
>>> stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
>>> stats = collections.Counter(stats)
>>> stats.most_common(1)
[('b', 3000)]
```

If appropriate, you could simply start with an empty `collections.Counter` and add to it

```
>>> stats = collections.Counter()
>>> stats['a'] += 1
:
etc.
```

Answer (score 12):

I got here looking for how to return `mydict.keys()` based on the value of `mydict.values()`. Instead of just the one key returned, I was looking to return the top *x* number of values.

This solution is simpler than using the `max()` function and you can easily change the number of values returned:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}

x = sorted(stats, key=(lambda key:stats[key]), reverse=True)
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

If you want the single highest ranking key, just use the index:

```
x[0]
['b']
```

If you want the top two highest ranking keys, just use list slicing:

```
x[:2]
['b', 'a']
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution. Sorting the dict will incur a runtime of n log (n) because you're concerning yourself with a bunch of values that are not the maximum. Using the max function will incur a runtime of just n which is much faster.

Comment: @PeterGraham pretty much every solution here (including the accepted answer) uses `max()`. It's clear it's the fastest. I thought I'd offer a different solution with the benefit of slicing, which was more useful to me at the time

Answer (score 11):

Much simpler to understand approach:

```
mydict = { 'a':302, 'e':53, 'g':302, 'h':100 }
max_value_keys = [key for key in mydict.keys() if mydict[key] == max(mydict.values())]
print(max_value_keys) # prints a list of keys with max value
```

**Output:** ['a', 'g']

Now you can choose only one key:

```
maximum = mydict[max_value_keys[0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

A heap queue is a **generalised** solution which allows you to extract the top *n* keys ordered by value:

```
from heapq import nlargest

stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}

res1 = nlargest(1, stats, key=stats.__getitem__)  # ['b']
res2 = nlargest(2, stats, key=stats.__getitem__)  # ['b', 'a']

res1_val = next(iter(res1))                       # 'b'
```

Note `dict.__getitem__` is the method called by the syntactic sugar `dict[]`. As opposed to `dict.get`, it will return `KeyError` if a key is not found, which here cannot occur.

Answer (score 5):

`max((value, key) for key, value in stats.items())[1]`

Comment: This will order by the key with duplicate max values. That may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 5):

Following are two easy ways to extract key with max value from given dict

```
import time
stats = {
   "a" : 1000,
   "b" : 3000,
   "c" : 90,
   "d" : 74,
   "e" : 72,
 }

start_time = time.time_ns()
max_key = max(stats, key = stats.get)
print("Max Key [", max_key, "]Time taken (ns)", time.time_ns() - start_time)

start_time = time.time_ns()
max_key = max(stats, key=lambda key: stats[key])
print("Max Key with Lambda[", max_key, "]Time taken (ns)", time.time_ns() - start_time)
```

> Output

```
Max Key [ b ] Time taken (ns) 3100
Max Key with Lambda [ b ] Time taken (ns) 1782
```

Solution with Lambda expression seems to be performing better for smaller inputs.

Answer (score 4):

For scientific python users, here is a simple solution using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series({'a': 1000, 'b': 3000, 'c': 100}).idxmax()

>>> b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Counter = 0
for word in stats.keys():
    if stats[word]> counter:
        Counter = stats [word]
print Counter
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to [@Aric Coady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary#comment73465439_280156)'s simplest solution. 
And also one way to random select one of keys with max value in the dictionary:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100, 'd':3000}

import random
maxV = max(stats.values())
# Choice is one of the keys with max value
choice = random.choice([key for key, value in stats.items() if value == maxV])
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested the accepted answer AND @thewolf's fastest solution against a very basic loop and the loop was faster than both:

```
import time
import operator


d = {"a"+str(i): i for i in range(1000000)}

def t1(dct):
    mx = float("-inf")
    key = None
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if v > mx:
            mx = v
            key = k
    return key

def t2(dct):
    v=list(dct.values())
    k=list(dct.keys())
    return k[v.index(max(v))]

def t3(dct):
    return max(dct.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

start = time.time()
for i in range(25):
    m = t1(d)
end = time.time()
print ("Iterating: "+str(end-start))

start = time.time()
for i in range(25):
    m = t2(d)
end = time.time()
print ("List creating: "+str(end-start))

start = time.time()
for i in range(25):
    m = t3(d)
end = time.time()
print ("Accepted answer: "+str(end-start))
```

results:

```
Iterating: 3.8201940059661865
List creating: 6.928712844848633
Accepted answer: 5.464320182800293
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of stats is empty, one can check a condition before finding valued key like,

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100}
max_key = None
if bool(stats):
   max_key = max(stats, key=stats.get)
print(max_key)
```

This can first check if the dictionary is empty or not, then process.

```
>>> b
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 max(zip(stats.keys(), stats.values()), key=lambda t : t[1])[0]
```

Comment: `zip(stats.keys(), stats.values())` is just a longer way to write `stats.items()`. Once you make that change, your answer will be almost identical to *several* older answers.

Comment: Agreed, I wasnt aware that items() is same as zip

Comment: `items` isn't the same as `zip`. It just produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you have more than one key with the same value, for example:

```
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100, 'd':3000, 'e':3000}
```

You could get a collection with all the keys with max value as follow:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

groupedByValue = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in sorted(stats.items()):
    groupedByValue[value].append(key)

# {1000: ['a'], 3000: ['b', 'd', 'e'], 100: ['c']}

groupedByValue[max(groupedByValue)]
# ['b', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Good point! This solution is much easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861776/10836415

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sorted(dict_name, key=dict_name.__getitem__, reverse=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a situation where you want to select certain keys instead of all of them:

````
stats = {'a':1000, 'b':3000, 'c': 100, 'd':3000, 'e':3000}
keys_to_search = ["a", "b", "c"]

max([k for k in keys_to_search], key=lambda x: stats[x])```
````