# Getting the maximum value from dictionary

Tags: python, rows, max, key-value-coding, python-2.4

I'm facing problem with this. I have 10,000 rows in my dictionary and this is one of the rows

Example: A (8) C (4) G (48419) T (2) when printed out

I'd like to get 'G' as an answer, since it has the highest value.

I'm currently using Python 2.4 and I have no idea how to solve this as I'm quite new in Python.

Thanks a lot for any help given :)

Comment: Give us two or three rows from your dictionary and respective output awaited.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Comment: Why are you using a release from 2005?

Comment: I submitted an answer to get the highest value from a single row, but is your actual use-case to get the highest value in the whole 10,000 row file? Or to get a list of highest values for every row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that

1. uses a regexp to scan all occurrences of an uppercase letter followed by a number in brackets
2. transforms the string pairs from the regexp with a generator expression into (value,key) tuples
3. returns the key from the tuple that has the highest value

I also added a main function so that the script can be used as a command line tool to read all lines from one file and the write the key with the highest value for each line to an output file. The program uses iterators, so that it is memory efficient no matter how large the input file is.

```
import re
KEYVAL = re.compile(r"([A-Z])\s*\((\d+)\)")

def max_item(row):
    return max((int(v),k) for k,v in KEYVAL.findall(row))[1]

def max_item_lines(fh):
    for row in fh:
        yield "%s\n" % max_item(row)

def process_file(infilename, outfilename):
    infile = open(infilename)
    max_items = max_item_lines(infile)
    outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
    outfile.writelines(max_items)
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    infilename, outfilename = sys.argv[1:]
    process_file(infilename, outfilename)
```

For a single row, you can call:

```
>>> max_item("A (8) C (4) G (48419) T (2)")
'G'
```

And to process a complete file:

```
>>> process_file("inputfile.txt", "outputfile.txt")
```

If you want an actual Python list of every row's maximum value, then you can use:

```
>>> map(max_item, open("inputfile.txt"))
```

Comment: Is there any other ways where I do not need to write it into the output file instead it's shown direct? Thanks

Comment: @Vincent: The last example should cover that.

Answer (score 1):

```
max(d.itervalues())
```

This will be much faster than say d.values() as it is using an iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
st = "A (8) C (4) G (48419) T (2)" # your start string
a=st.split(")")
b=[x.replace("(","").strip() for x in a if x!=""]
c=[x.split(" ") for x in b]
d=[(int(x[1]),x[0]) for x in c]
max(d) # this is your result.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to split the line. Then for all the matched groups, you have to convert the matched strings to numbers, get the maximum, and figure out the corresponding letter.

```
import re
r = re.compile('A \((\d+)\) C \((\d+)\) G \((\d+)\) T \((\d+)\)')
for line in my_file:
  m = r.match(line)
  if not m:
    continue # or complain about invalid line
  value, n = max((int(value), n) for (n, value) in enumerate(m.groups()))
  print "ACGT"[n], value
```

Comment: Sorry, this is Python2.6. You can do this in Python2.4, but you'll probably need square brackets inside max, i.e. max([...]).

Comment: In Python2.6 the following works and returns `9`: `max(i for i in xrange(10))`

Comment: 2.4 is old and not so shiny, and it lacks most of Python's more recent awesomeness. But it does have generator expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I've used regular expression in the earlier part and it works fine. Can I use this to find out the highest value from A(8)C(4)G(48419)T(2)                                                 from operator import itemgetter
 d = a_value, c_value, g_value, t_value
 sorted(d, key=itemgetter(0))
 print d

Comment: itemgetter won't help you this way: first you need to pair the number with the value you want to return (i.e. A, C, G, T). Other answers achieve the same with reversing and sorting tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
row = "A (8) C (4) G (48419) T (2)"

lst = row.replace("(",'').replace(")",'').split() # ['A', '8', 'C', '4', 'G', '48419', 'T', '2']

dd = dict(zip(lst[0::2],map(int,lst[1::2]))) # {'A': 8, 'C': 4, 'T': 2, 'G': 48419} 

max(map(lambda k:[dd[k],k], dd))[1] # 'G'
```