# implementing argmax in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

How should argmax be implemented in Python?  It should be as efficient as possible, so it should work with iterables.

Three ways it could be implemented:

- given an iterable of pairs return the key corresponding to the greatest value
- given an iterable of values return the index of the greatest value
- given an iterable of keys and a function `f`, return the key with largest `f(key)`

Comment: argmax on what? A function, a dictionary?

Comment: on two iterables like in math: argmax_{keys} corresponding_values so that it returns the key corresponding to the greatest value.

Comment: If they are associated key-value pairs, why not store them in an associative data structure such as a dictionary?

Comment: This may be of interest to you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Comment: I guess you could do that, but my solution to argmax would have to unzip dict.items() and them re-zip it as (values, keys).

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that max could take a key.

Comment: @Neil G: Please **update** the question so that it makes sense to someone who doesn't already know the answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I modified the best solution I found:

```
# given an iterable of pairs return the key corresponding to the greatest value
def argmax(pairs):
    return max(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

# given an iterable of values return the index of the greatest value
def argmax_index(values):
    return argmax(enumerate(values))

# given an iterable of keys and a function f, return the key with largest f(key)
def argmax_f(keys, f):
    return max(keys, key=f)
```

Comment: (I thought this was worth sharing since I couldn't find it on SO.  If someone has a better solution, please share it!)

Comment: I would recommend using regular zip instead of itertools.izip. Use of itertools is kind of frowned on unless you have a very good reason to use it.

Comment: Although to be fair, izip returns an iterator while zip returns a list. So izip is faster if speed is important.

Comment: You can also use lambda x: x[1] instead of operator.itemgetter(1). It looks a bit nicer, I think.

Comment: @Swiss, as you point out izip is faster in some circumstances.  Anyway, in python3, izip is renamed zip, right?

Comment: @Swiss: I don't know where you got the idea that `itertools` was ever frowned upon. It was added to the standard library so it would be a readily available tool.

Comment: @Neil: something that *is* frowned upon is using a `lambda` expression as the right hand side of an assignment statement. Use an ordinary named function instead.

Comment: @ncoghlan, did not know that.  I will change them now, but would you happen to have a reference by any chance?

Comment: I don't know if it is written down anywhere - it's just in the assignment scenario you suffer all the drawbacks of using `lambda` without gaining any of the benefits, so a named function makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @ncoghlan Usually there are more "pythonic" ways of doing the same things as what is provided by itertools. map and filter weren't even planned to be in Python 3 originally: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @Swiss you're confounding ``itertools`` with ``functools`` -- map and reduce are in the latter.

Answer (score 21):

Is the following code a fast and pythonic way?

```
idx_max = max(enumerate(x), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

Comment: While this is basically a stripped down and uncommented version of the accepted answer, I found it more useful, and a `lambda` is easier to read than `operator` stuff (even if you don't use it in a final solution)

Answer (score 8):

```
def argmax(lst):
     return lst.index(max(lst))
```

or analogously:

```
argmax = lambda lst: lst.index(max(lst)
```

Comment: This approach is theoretically suboptimal because it iterates over the list twice.  However, it is elegant.

Comment: In fact, this one is faster then any other solutions posted here.

Answer (score 8):

I found this way easier to think about argmax: say we want to calculate `argmax(f(y))` where `y` is an item from `Y`. So for each `y` we want to calculate `f(y)` and get `y` with maximum `f(y)`.

This definition of argmax is general, unlike "given an iterable of values return the index of the greatest value" (and it is also quite natural IMHO).

And ..drumroll.. Python allows to do exactly this using a built-in `max`:

```
best_y = max(Y, key=f)
```

So `argmax_f` (from the accepted answer) is unnecesary complicated and inefficient IMHO - it is a complicated version of built-in `max`. All other argmax-like tasks should become clear at this point: just define a proper function `f`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Neil's answer, but specialized for functions that take multiple arguments.

```
argmax = lambda keys, func: max(imap(lambda key: (func(*key), key), keys))[1]
```

For example:

```
argmax([(5, 2), (3, 3), (2, 5)], pow)
# (2, 5)
```

Comment: With list comprehension instead of imap: max([(func(*key), key) for key in keys])

Comment: Generator is pretty much identical if you want to match imap's speed. max((func(*key), key) for key in keys)

Comment: @Swiss - list comprehension form is useful for those still on old versions of Python, pre-generator-expressions. But you are right, there is a performance penalty in creating the temporary list, just so you can get the max() of it.