# Python Priority Queue with objects heappush does not support '>' between objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue, heapq

In my attempt to implement a simple version of A* Search, I am trying to enqueue the following in a priority queue:

- Priority: sum of heuristic value and cost from source to current element
- Queue Node: Object of class queue node with data members point and cost
  The code goes something like this:
  '''s = queueNode(start, 0)
  q.put((s.dist + heuristics[s.pt[0]][s.pt[1]],s))  # Enqueue source cell'''

However, it gives the following error:
**in _put
heappush(self.queue, item)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'queueNode' and 'queueNode'**

Here is the code for class Queue Node

```
class queueNode:
    def __init__(self, pt, dist: int):
        self.pt = pt  # The cordinates of the cell
        self.dist = dist  # Cell's distance from the source
```

**update:**
I tried to make the classes comparable by these two Implementations

**First**

```
class queueNode:
def __init__(self, pt, dist):
    self.pt = pt  # The cordinates of the cell
    self.dist = dist  # Cell's distance from the source

def __it__(self,other):
    return self.dist < other.dist
```

**Second**

```
class queueNode:
def __init__(self, pt, dist):
    self.pt = pt  # The cordinates of the cell
    self.dist = dist  # Cell's distance from the source

def __it__(self,other):
    return id(self) < id(other)
```

it still gives the same error

**Update:**
A workaround to this is to use a list object instead of priority queue and sort it everytime you enter a new element.
**CODE**
q=[]
**APPENDING**
q.append((heuristics[i][j],queueNodeObject))
**SORTING ON BASIS OF COST**

```
def sort(q):
    #start stop step
    for i in range(0,q.__len__(),1):
        for j in range(i+1,q.__len__()-1,1):
            if q[i][0]<q[j][0]:
#q[i] returns the element in queue list i.e tuple=(cost, object) q[i][0] returns #the cost
                temp=q[i]
                q[i]=q[j]
                q[j]=temp
```

Comment: Your class needs to support "comparison".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907323/comparable-classes-in-python-3

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. I implemented all the functions in my class queueNode the error still persists though

Comment: Inside class queueNode you implemented `def __lt__(self, other): ....` and you get the same error message?

Comment: @FrankYellin yes, i'll edit the updated code

Comment: Did you ever post your code in which you implemented __lt__?   With all due respect, your sort algorithm is a really slow algorithm.  And the whole goal of a heap is that you perform an O(log n) operation after every insertion; you're performing an O(n^2) operation after each insertion.

Comment: @FrankYellin Just did