# Interviewbit - Merge k sorted linked lists: heappop returns max element instead of min

Tags: python-3.x, heap, heapq

I'm solving the Interviewbit code challenge [Merge K Sorted Lists](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/):

> Merge k sorted linked lists and return it as one sorted list.
>
> **Example :**
>
> ```
> 1 -> 10 -> 20
> 4 -> 11 -> 13
> 3 -> 8 -> 9
> ```
>
> will result in
>
> ```
> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 13 -> 20
> ```

The Python template code is:

> ```
> # Definition for singly-linked list.
> # class ListNode:
> #     def __init__(self, x):
> #         self.val = x
> #         self.next = None
>
> class Solution:
>     # @param A : list of linked list
>     # @return the head node in the linked list
>     def mergeKLists(self, A):
>         pass
> ```

Here's my python 3 solution for the same:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush
class Solution:
    # @param A : list of linked list
    # @return the head node in the linked list
    def mergeKLists(self, A):
        minheap = [x for x in A]
        # print(minheap)
        # heapify(minheap)
        # print(minheap)
        head = tail = None 
        # print(minheap)
        while minheap: 
            # print(minheap)
            heapify(minheap)
            print([x.val for x in minheap])
            minimum = heappop(minheap)
            print(minimum.val)
            if head is None:
                head = minimum
                tail = minimum
            else:
                tail.next = minimum
                tail = minimum
            
            if minimum.next:
                heappush(minheap, minimum.next)

        return head
```

With the print commands that are uncommented, you'll notice that in the intermediate runs of the while loop, `heappop` returns the largest element, as if we were dealing with a max heap, which we're not!
That's the place where the answer is going wrong as far as I can see. Can anyone suggest the reason for why heappop is working like this? And how that can be corrected?

Comment: „ you'll notice“ I’m afraid we don’t, since we cannot actually run the code with what is in the question. Please take another look at the [ask] and especially the [mre] help pages and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Note that heapq already ships with a helper to merge multiple iterable, provide each is internally sorted.

Comment: Hi. Provided the link to the exact question so that it can be reproduced exactly in the settings in which it is being attempted. Hope that helps and apologies for the earlier oversight.

Comment: No. Again, please take a look at the [mre] help page. Do not rely on external services being available to the people you are asking for help. Cut down the code to only the critical parts, provide a small sample input by hardcoding it into a piece of code that calls your algorithm properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code locally with sample data, I get an error on:

```
    heapify(minheap)
```

> TypeError: `<` not supported between instances of `ListNode` and `ListNode`

This is expected. The template definition of `ListNode` shows no support for making comparisons, and a heapify function will need to compare the items in the given list.

As the class `ListNode` is already defined by the code-challenge framework, it is probably better not to try to [make that class comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907323/comparable-classes-in-python-3).

I would propose to put tuples on the heap which have list node instances as members, but have their `val` attribute value come first, followed by the number of the list (in `A`) they originate from. As third tuple member you'd finally have the node itself. This way comparisons will work, since tuples are comparable when their members are. And since the second tuple member will be a tie-breaker when the first member value is the same, the third tuple member (the list node instance) will never be subject to a comparison.

Unrelated to your question, but you should only heapify *once*, not in each iteration of the loop. The actions on the heap (`heappush`, `heappop`) maintain the heap property, so there is no need for calling `heapify` a second time. If you do it in each iteration, you actually destroy the efficiency benefit you would get from using a heap.

Here is your code updated with that change:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush

class Solution:
    def mergeKLists(self, A):
        # place comparable tuples in the heap 
        minheap = [(node.val, i, node) for i, node in enumerate(A)]
        heapify(minheap)  # call only once
        head = tail = None 
        while minheap: 
            # extract the tuple information we need
            _, i, minimum = heappop(minheap)
            if head is None:
                head = minimum
                tail = minimum
            else:
                tail.next = minimum
                tail = minimum
            
            minimum = minimum.next
            if minimum:
                # push a tuple, using same list index
                heappush(minheap, (minimum.val, i, minimum))

        return head
```