# Unorderable type error while pushing into heap

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, heap, heapq

I have a list of heads of N Linked Lists which I am trying to merge based on their value using heaps.

Since `heapq` works with first value in tuples for sorting in heap I wrote the following code:

```
 def mergeKLists(self, A): # A contains list of Linked list heads
    nodeList = []
    for i in A:
        nodeList.append((i.val,i)) # Creating a list of tuples : (value, Node address)
    heapq.heapify(nodeList)
    print(nodeList)
```

This works fine and creates a heap sorted on the 1st value in tuple. However when I am trying to push more elements on this heap it gives me a unordered type error:

```
    t = heapq.heappop(nodeList)
    node  = t[1]
    heapq.heappush(nodeList,(node.next.val,node.next)) # this throws error for node.next parameter
```

The error I get:

```
heapq.heappush(nodeList,(node.next.val,node))
TypeError: unorderable types: ListNode() < ListNode()
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error will occur when the input lists have duplicate values. In that case the comparison of two tuples having the same first tuple member, will result in a comparison of the *second* tuple members, which is an operation that is not defined.

To avoid this error, either make the `ListNode` instances [comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907323/comparable-classes-in-python-3), or add a member in your tuples, in the middle, which is unique:

```
nodeList.append((i.val, id(i), i))
```

...and adapt the rest of your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks this was the issue. Added index of list as middle element of tuple and works fine now.