# Type hint for "can be compared" objects

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am writing several functions that handle ordered datasets.
Sometime, there is an argument that can be a `int` or `float` or a timestamp or anything that supports comparison (larger than / smaller than) and that I can use for trimming data for instance.

Is there a way to type-hint such a parameter? The typing module doesn't seem to include this, but is there some other way?

Comment: There's really no such thing as broad as "supports comparison". `int` values, for example, can be compared to other numbers, but not strings.

Comment: I would do something like ComparableMixin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907323/comparable-classes-in-python-3) and check for objects that inherit from it. But as @chepner wrote, I'm afraid this is not quite generic as in other languages e.g. C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard 'comparable' ABC, no, as the rich comparison methods are really very flexible and don't necessarily return booleans.

The default built-in types return `NotImplemented` when applied to a type they can't be compared with, for example, while specialised libraries like SQLAlchemy and numpy use rich comparison methods to return completely different objects. See the [documentation for the rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) for the details.

But you should be able to define a
a [`Protocol` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) for specific expectations:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Comparable(Protocol[T]):
    def __eq__(self: T, other: T) -> bool:
        ...

    def __lt__(self: T, other: T) -> bool:
        ...

    # ... etc
```

You may need to tweak the protocol to fit your exact expectations, and / or use a non-generic version that's specific to the types you use (perhaps with `@overload`ed definitions for specific types).

For sorting with the builtin `sorted()` function, `__eq__` and `__lt__` suffice.