# Parsing through a dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

By using iterations and comprehensions, I created a python dictionary that stores keys associated with values (stats related to certain features). The keys, refer to an unique ID (in my case, a gene). I have populated the values by a list of tuples each indicating the **startpoint** and **length** of a feature (in this case, an **ORF** or in other words **potential protein coding sequence**) of the gene ID. Any given gene can have many such features. The general form is as under:

```
{key1:[(startpoint1,length1)], key2[(startpoint1,length1)(startpoint2,length2)...], key3[]}
```

As shown below (in a sample dictionary), some keys could have only one feature (only one tuple pair), while others could have as many as 100 or more. For simplicity, I have shown seq1 with 3 pairs. Also there can be keys with no features, for example, seq3 and 4.

`{'seq2': [(1,6)], 'seq1': [(1, 12), (16, 9), (32,9)], 'seq3': [], 'seq4': []}`

I want to iterate through this dictionary to get the "startpoint" when the "length" is maximum. In my example the answer I should get is

> **startpoint 1** (in seq1), because it has biggest **length value (12)** among all the entries.

I find it hard to iterate over multiple tuples.

Comment: What do you find hard in iterating over multiple tuples? Are you facing any issue with any attempts? If so please post that as well as the issue you are facing with it

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098580/implementing-argmax-in-python  also notice [max can take an iterable and a custom function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` , passing it the `dict.values()` (list of all values in your dictionary) . And then use `max` with the key argument, to get back the tuple with maximum values at second index ( 1-index), Example -

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> d = {'seq2': [(1,6)], 'seq1': [(1, 12), (16, 9), (32,9)], 'seq3': [], 'seq4': []}
>>> max(chain.from_iterable(d.values()),key=lambda x: x[1])
(1, 12)
```

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` , takes the iterable it gets as input and chains each up into a single list, Example -

```
>>> l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(l))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had tried by nesting for loops and getting lost in the syntax.

Comment: You might want to use `itervalues` instead of `values` to reduce memory foot print: `values` create a copy the dictionary's values, whereas `itervalues` does not.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should do.

```
myDict = {'seq2': [(1,6)], 'seq1': [(1, 12), (16, 9), (32,9)], 'seq3': [], 'seq4': []}

maxLength = 0;
maxStartingPoint = 0;
maxSeq = ""

for sequence in myDict:

    for key,value in myDict[sequence]:
        if value > maxLength:
            maxLength = value
            maxStartingPoint = key
            maxSeq = sequence
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice iteration though a dictionary of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach: create a list of tuples `(length, start_point, key)`, this way, the `max` function can just pick the tuple with the maximum length.

```
def maxlen(seq):
    longest = max((length, start_point, key) for key, value in seq.iteritems() for start_point, length in value)
    return longest

# Test
seq = {'seq2': [(1,6)], 'seq1': [(1, 12), (16, 9), (32,9)], 'seq3': [], 'seq4': []}
length, start_point, key = maxlen(seq)  # 12, 1, 'seq1'
```