# Group strings with values in Python

Tags: python, grouping, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I'm working on twitter hashtags and I've already counted the number of times they appear in my csv file. My csv file look like:

```
GilletsJaunes, 100
Macron, 50
gilletsjaune, 20
tax, 10
```

Now, I would like to group together 2 terms that are close, such as "GilletsJaunes" and "gilletsjaune" using the fuzzywuzzy library. If the proximity between the 2 terms is greater than 80, then their value is added in only one of the 2 terms and the other is deleted. This would give:

```
GilletsJaunes, 120
Macron, 50
tax, 10
```

For use "fuzzywuzzy":

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

fuzz.ratio("GiletsJaunes", "giletsjaune")
82 #output
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your attempt so that we can help you correct it.

Answer (score 2):

First, copy [these two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098586/) to be able to compute the argmax:

```
# given an iterable of pairs return the key corresponding to the greatest value
def argmax(pairs):
    return max(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]


# given an iterable of values return the index of the greatest value
def argmax_index(values):
    return argmax(enumerate(values))
```

Second, load the content of your CSV into a Python dictionary and proceed as follows:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

input = {
    'GilletsJaunes': 100,
    'Macron': 50,
    'gilletsjaune': 20,
    'tax': 10,
}

threshold = 50

output = dict()
for query in input:
    references = list(output.keys()) # important: this is output.keys(), not input.keys()!
    scores = [fuzz.ratio(query, ref) for ref in references]
    if any(s > threshold for s in scores):
        best_reference = references[argmax_index(scores)]
        output[best_reference] += input[query]
    else:
        output[query] = input[query]

print(output)
```

> {'GilletsJaunes': 120, 'Macron': 50, 'tax': 10}

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem. You can reduce your input sample by first converting your tags to lowercase. I'm not sure how fuzzywuzzy works, but I would suspect that "HeLlO" and "hello" and "HELLO" are always going to be greater than an 80, and they represent the same word.

```
import csv
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

data = dict()
output = dict()
tags = list()

with open('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        data[row[0]] = row[1]
        tags.append(row[0])

for tag in tags:
    output[tag] = 0
    for key in data.keys():
        if fuzz.ratio(tag, key) > 80:
            output[tag] = output[tag] + data[key]
```