# Find keys of the largest 4 values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's part of my Python code, I'm trying to find the 4 consecutive values in `spec` which yields the maximum sum, and then find the weighted average value of the corresponding 4 keys:

```
spec = {1.5:8, 1.3:9, 4.3:7, 3.2:3, 5.3:5, 4:1, 5.2:6, 4.2:4, 2.5:9} 
k = 4
consecutive_elements = zip(*(islice(spec.values(), x, None) for x in range(k)))
max(map(sum, consecutive_elements)) # The maximum sum.
Wavg = np.average(list(???.keys()), weights=list(???.values())) # The weighted average
```

I'm not sure how I can access the 4 keys. In this case, they should be `1.5, 1.3, 4.3, 3.2` since the sum of their values is 27 (the maximum). Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not really a mapping as much as a pair of sequences with corresponding elements. I would recommend visualizing it as such:

```
keys = list(spec.keys())
vals = list(spec.keys())
```

From here it should be pretty clear how to do using something like [implementing argmax in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5098580/2988730):

```
consecutive_elements = zip(*(islice(spec.values(), x, None) for x in range(k)))
idx = max(enumerate(map(sum, consecutive_elements)), key=itemgetter(1))[0] # The maximum sum.
Wavg = sum(a * b for a, b in zip(keys[idx:idx + k], vals[idx:idx + k])) / sum(vals[idx:idx + k])
```

That being said, if you're using numpy anyway, I'd say commit to it:

```
keys = np.fromiter(spec.keys(), float, count=len(spec))
vals = np.fromiter(spec.values(), float, count=len(spec))

idx = np.convolve(vals, np.ones(k), 'valid').argmax()
Wavg = np.average(keys[idx:idx + k], weights=vals[idx:idx + k])
```

The results from both versions are exactly identical:

```
2.348148148148148
```

Comment: @ZR-. Glad it worked for you. I added an update