# Highest value of a number from a list of modes

Tags: python, list, frequency

So I have found the frequencies of numbers from a list and have created a list such as this [2:3 , 25:1, 22:4, 5:2, 5:2] What im trying to do after that is have a for loop detecting the maximum frequency (different numbers can have the same frequencies) and then printing the number and frequency that is the highest which may be more than one.

Comment: Do you have a `list` or a `dict`? Because `[2:3 , 25:1, 22:4, 5:2, 5:2]` is neither.

Comment: So, in `2:3`, which is the number and which is the frequency? Also, what is the significance of `5:2` appearing twice?

Comment: So number is 2 and frequency is 3.  Umm trying to show that different numbers can have the same max frequency

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Comment: My guess is for 2:3 you get the frequency when you divide 2 by 3.
@bluelantem some clarification would help. What's the datatype of a
single list entry?

Comment: The Number is 2, the frequency is 3

Comment: So it's a dictionary? I.e. {2:3 , 25:1, 22:4, 5:2}? Why does 5:2 appear twice? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes my bad sorry a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your data is structured

```
>>> data = {2:3 , 25:1, 22:4, 5:2, 5:2}
>>> max(data, key = lambda x: data[x])
22
```

or

```
>>> data = [(2, 3), (25, 1), (22, 4), (5,2), (5,2)]
>>> max(data, key = lambda x: x[1])
(22, 4)
```

should do the trick.

**[Edit]**

```
>>> data = {2:3 , 25:4, 22:4, 5:2, 5:2}
>>> max_key = max(data.values())
>>> print [i for i in data if data[i] == max_key]
[22, 25]
```

Comment: Lets say you have data = {2:4, 5:4, 3:2, 22:6} how would you display 2 and 5

Comment: Edited, this will take into account multiple values. You are using a bad data structure though. I strongly suggest you to take a look at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter