# Normalizing dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a (quite large) dictionary that has numeric values, so for example in the form `data = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.3, ...}`. What is the best way to normalize these values (EDIT: make sure the values sum to 1)?

And what I'm especially interested in: Would it, for certain dataset size, be beneficial to use for example numpy instead of dict comprehension?

I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: What do you mean by normalize?

Comment: The sum of values should equal one.

Comment: Do you want to replace the values in your original dictionary, or do you want a new one?

Comment: As @jamylak said: inplace modification is better here, since creating a new dict wouldn't be very memory-efficient and I can afford to lose the old data.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this to modify in place:

```
d={'a':0.2, 'b':0.3}
factor=1.0/sum(d.itervalues())
for k in d:
  d[k] = d[k]*factor
```

result:

```
>>> d
{'a': 0.4, 'b': 0.6}
```

Alternatively to modify into a new dictionary, use a dict comprehension:

```
d={'a':0.2, 'b':0.3}
factor=1.0/sum(d.itervalues())
normalised_d = {k: v*factor for k, v in d.iteritems() }
```

Note the use of d.iteritems() which uses less memory than d.items(), so is better for a large dictionary.

**EDIT**: Since there are quite a few of them, and getting this right seems to be important, I've summarised all the ideas in the comments to this answer together to the following (including borrowing something from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)):

```
import math
import operator

def really_safe_normalise_in_place(d):
    factor=1.0/math.fsum(d.itervalues())
    for k in d:
        d[k] = d[k]*factor
    key_for_max = max(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    diff = 1.0 - math.fsum(d.itervalues())
    #print "discrepancy = " + str(diff)
    d[key_for_max] += diff

d={v: v+1.0/v for v in xrange(1, 1000001)}
really_safe_normalise_in_place(d)
print math.fsum(d.itervalues())
```

Took a couple of goes to come up with dictionary that actually created a non-zero error when normalising but hope this illustrates the point.

**EDIT:** For Python 3.0. see the following change:
Python 3.0 Wiki [Built-in Changes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0#Built-In_Changes)

> Remove `dict.iteritems()`, `dict.iterkeys()`, and `dict.itervalues()`.
>
> Instead: use `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()`, and `dict.values()`
>   respectively.

Comment: better use `d.itervalues` (since you are iterating through the values twice & storing them in a list in memory if you use `d.values()`)

Comment: Thanks - that's a good point. I've updated to use itervalues.

Comment: To improve accuracy, use *math.fsum()* instead of *sum()*.   With the OP's large dictionary, there's more potential for loss of accuracy during summation, resulting in a *factor* that is a little off.

Comment: Also, to make sure the sum is *exactly* one, there can be a final pass the "plug the difference" back into the values.  For example, this is what people do when they split a dollar three ways into 33 cents, 33 cents, and 34 cents.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger do you need a final pass or can you just add the difference to a random key with a running sum?

Comment: Actually you would probably need to `fsum` again so the final pass would be needed

Comment: @jamylak I would make a final pass using *math.fsum()* and then plug the difference in the value with the largest magnitude.  That should get you to a total of exactly 1.0 and would minimize the relative error of the adjusted value.

Comment: Might want to check if the sum of values is 0, otherwise you might get an error.

Answer (score 6):

```
def normalize(d, target=1.0):
   raw = sum(d.values())
   factor = target/raw
   return {key:value*factor for key,value in d.iteritems()}
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> data = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.3, 'c': 1.5}
>>> normalize(data)
{'b': 0.15, 'c': 0.75, 'a': 0.1}
```

Comment: You need iteritems for python 2.x though.

Comment: The dictionary is quite large so it would be better to modify it inplace

Comment: @Jaapsneep: I didn't see the Python 2.7 reference when I first read the question. Thanks.