# Pandas: get index of each element

Tags: python, pandas

I guess this is a duplicate of  [Find element's index in pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18327624/1948860) .

This is my dataframe;

```
      WORD1    CAT1   
    elephant   animal  
        lion   animal
       tiger   animal
      hoopoe    bird 
    hornbill    bird
   sunflower   flower
        rose   flower
     giraffe   animal
       zebra   animal
     sparrow    bird  
        duck   animal
```

I would like to get the index of each element from 'CAT1';

Let me put it this way;

```
for d in data['CAT1']:
    print data[data['CAT1'] == d].index[0]
...
0
0
0
3
3
5
5
0
0
3
0
```

The above returns the index, but falters when there are duplicates. How do I get this rectified?

Comment: For future readers of this question, could you update to be clearer about what you actually *want* as an output? "get the index of each element from 'CAT1'" is ambiguous. Do you want the *first* index of each distinct entry in `CAT1` or do you want to assign each distinct entry a number and replace the text with this number?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in Python to get the indices along with the items:

```
for i, d in enumerate(data['CAT1']):
     print(i)
```

If you want to select from `WORD1` by `CAT1`, you could [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them, for example:

```
birds = [w for w, c in zip(data['WORD1'], data['CAT1']) if c == "bird")]
```

Note: [`str.index`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) is a method for finding the index of a sub-string within a string.

Comment: As you've seen, `list.index` gives you the *first index only*. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve; have you tried the suggestions in my answer?

Comment: @jonrharpe yes. Tried it. Makes sense. But I'm looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18327624/1948860

Comment: The answers there cover this too, you can use `data['CAT1'].get_loc(d)` or `data[data['CAT1'] == d]`