# find first matching value in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a function that can be applied to a pandas column that is equivalent to the *index* function of python list? I.e. search a column for a particular value, then break when it encounters first instance of that value and return the index.

eg.

```
l = ['a','b','b']
l.index('b')
```

returns 1.

The closest I can find in Pandas , if the same data was in a column:

```
(l == 'b').nonzero()[0][0]
```

Which seems a bit wasteful in instances where I have a big column with lots of repeat values

Comment: Looks like it's been asked and discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327624/find-elements-index-in-pandas-series)

Comment: @JonClements agreed. I have marked as duplicate. Shame there is no satisfactory answer there...

Comment: okay... wasn't sure to vote to close, but if you're happy that's a dupe that's fine... (might be worth as it's come up a couple of times making an issue on the project tracker/see if there's already an issue but no resolution and give it a chase or something...)