# get index value from merged pandas time series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have various time series pandas data frames which look like:

data['F_NQ'] =

`OPEN   HIGH    LOW  CLOSE     VOL      OI  P  R  RINFO
DATE

1996-04-10  12450  12494  12200  12275    2282     627  0  0      0
1996-04-11  12200  12360  12000  12195    1627     920  0  0      0`

I merged these into one dataframe so that I could select by date using concat
`mergeData = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=data.keys())`

Now I can get a slice for a chunk of time:
`timeSlice = mergeData.loc[startDate:endDate]`

my problem is that I am looping over that timeSlice object and selecting a particular day based on the index number...

`selectedDay = timeSlice.iloc[n]`

I need to know the DATE for the selected row.  How do I access that location value?  If I provide the location value with: `selectedDay = timeSlice.loc[date]` the correct information is returned.  At the time I'm making the call however I don't know the date.  How do I get at that information?

Comment: if the date is your index, you could do `date  = timeSlice.iloc[n].name` is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me find the solution... [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327624/find-elements-index-in-pandas-series)

I basically need to call: `timeSlice.index[-1]` to get the last date from whichever time block I've selected.

Answer (score 0):

since `.iloc[n]` return a pandas series with the index has the name, you could get the name of that series doing this :

```
date = timeSlice.iloc[n].name
```