# python pandas print specific location of a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, location

I have looked at other solutions online but none of them work on my dataframe.
I want to get the exact location of a specific datetime object but this code produces this keyerror `KeyError: '2018-1-31'`

```
import pandas as pd    
data=pd.DataFrame()
dti = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=10, freq="M")
data['dti']=dti
print((data['dti'].loc['2018-1-31'])) # it should print 0 since this date is in the first row
```

Answer (score 0):

'dti' is not the index, so you cannot use `loc` directly. You need to generate a boolean Series first:

```
data.loc[data['dti'].eq('2018-1-31'), 'dti']
```

output:

```
0   2018-01-31
Name: dti, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

to get the index:

```
data.loc[data['dti'].eq('2018-1-31'), 'dti'].index
```

Comment: thanks, and how do you print all locations between two dates ?

Comment: depends on the data (sorted or not, duplicates or not). Can you provide an example in your question (input and output)?

Comment: i added these lines to the code above to calculate the mean of another column between two dates : data['nr']=range(10)
print(data)
print(data.loc[(data['dti'] >= (2018-1-31) & df['timestamp'] <= (2018, 4, 30)), 'nr'].mean()) and it generates a typeerror.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following to get index ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18327852/5916727)):

```
data[data['dti']=='2018-01-31'].index[0]
```

Output is:

```
0
```

And if you want indices for the range, you could using `&` for the condition to filter, may be something like below:

```
data[(data['dti']>'2018-2-28') & (data['dti']<'2018-6-30')].index.tolist()
```

Output is:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```