# Getting the Max Value from a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm sure this is very easy:

say I have the following dictionary:

```
 foo = { a: 3, b: 10, c: 5 }
```

What's the most efficient (and cleanest) way to get the value 10

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're only concerned about finding the max value, and not the key relating to it, then you just access the values of the dict (although the linked post [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary) is definitely worth a read)

On Python 2.x:

```
max(foo.itervalues())
```

On Python 3.x:

```
max(foo.values())
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the max value of the dictionary. You can do this:

```
>>> d = {'a':5,'b':10,'c':5}
>>> d.get(max(d, key=d.get))
10
```

**Explanation:**
max(d, key=d.get) => Gets the key with the maximum value where d is the dictionary
d.get => gets the value associated with that key

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does work, but also introduces lots of function calls for key lookups... so all adding unnecessary overhead...

Comment: @JonClements I agree. You have a better solution as you are using iterations. But this works too.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have the following Counter object:

```
from collections import Counter
foo = Counter({ "a": 3, "b": 10, "c": 5 })
```

You can then use the `.most_common()` method to get a list of tuples sorted by most to least:

```
>>> foo.most_common()
[('b', 10), ('c', 5), ('a', 3)]
```

To get the *max* just grab the first element:

```
foo_max = foo.most_common()[0]
```

Comment: That's if the object is a `collections.Counter` - and even then, `most_common` isn't really designed for that... It's pretty much like doing `sorted(foo.values(), reverse=True)[0]`