# Python extract max value from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary of the form:

```
 {'2015-01-01': {'time': '8', 'capacity': '5'}, 
  '2015-01-02': {'time': '8', 'capacity': '7'},
  '2015-01-03': {'time': '8', 'capacity': '8'} etc}
```

The dictionary is created from a csv file using dictreader. What I would like to be able to do is return the maximum value of capacity. So in this case 8.

I can use:

```
for k,v in input_dict.items():
    if temp_max < int(v['capacity']):
        temp_max = int(v['capacity'])
```

which works but I wondered if there was a neater method? I've searched and found methods to extract the top level key associated with the maximum value which is of course not what I need. See below:

```
max(input_dict, key=lambda v: input_dict[v]['capacity'])
```

which would return '2015-01-03', So I imagine there is a simple mod to the above one liner that will give me what I need but is has me stumped!

Any ideas?

Comment: `input_dict[max(input_dict, key=lambda v: input_dict[v]['capacity'])]` is this what you need

Comment: @JonSurrell to late :P

Comment: Maybe you can configure and use that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/268285/3955539 for your problem.

Comment: @VigneshKalai is was missing `['capacity']` at the end as well, it was returning full entry.

Comment: yeah forgot that bit @JonSurrell thanks

Comment: No that would return the nested dictionary not just the capacity within that nest dictionary. So in the above example:  {'time': '8', 'capacity': '8'}

Comment: Vignesh. Thanks your answer is correct but Bruno's answer below is neater so I marked his as correct. Many thanks though as like I say your answer is not wrong!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want

```
max(int(d['capacity']) for d in input_dict.values())
```

Explanation:

If you don't care about the keys, just iterate over the nested dicts (IOW the outer dict's values)

Also your inner dicts "capacity" values are stored as strings, I assume you want to test the integer value. To find out the difference check this:

```
>>> max(["1", "5", "18", "01"])
'5'
>>> max([1, 5, 18, 01])
18
>>>
```

Comment: To be overly-rigorous, this returns the `int` modified value, where the original value was a string.

Comment: Also works and I think neater than the other answer so I will mark this correct. Yes I want to test integer values. They appear as strings from being read in via the csv dictreader.

Comment: is there a way to extract this together with the key?

Answer (score 0):

Take every number at capacity and check for the max:

```
>>> myDict =  {'2015-01-01': {'time': '8', 'capacity': '5'}, 
  '2015-01-02': {'time': '8', 'capacity': '7'},
  '2015-01-03': {'time': '8', 'capacity': '8'} }
>>> max_capacity = max([int(i['capacity']) for i in myDict.values()])
>>> max_capacity
8
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this a long boring way

```
print max(input_dict.items(), key=lambda v: int(input_dict[v[0]]['capacity']))[1]['capacity']
```

But wait why did this `max(input_dict, key=lambda v: input_dict[v]['capacity'])` not work `OMG` the reason to that is

When you call `max(input_dict, key=lambda v: input_dict[v]['capacity'])` input_dict dicts keys are called so you get the output which is the `key with highest capacity`

**Notes:**

- What I have done in my max function is I called dictionaries `item` function which `returns the key and value in List of set` since I have used a list of set as test sample I will get a set as output from max function.
- The first value would be the `key` and the second value would be the `value`
- So after applying the max function I would get a set with two values one is key and the other is it's corresponding value so you could use `[1]['capacity']` to get `capacity` value