# I need to calculate the range of the max overlapping occurances not the max number of them

Tags: python, pseudocode

Assume that I have a dataset with numbers (start, stop):

```
4556745  ,  4556749
4556749  ,  5078554
```

… and so on

I want to make a chunk of code in order to print the range (start, stop) in which the max overlapping is occurred.
Till now I have managed to calculate the max number of occurrences but not the range in which they are in.

My pseudocode  – logic is like this :

```
maxoverlap =  zero
currentoverlap = zero
i equals zero
j equals zero
m equals len(in_mumbers) 
n equals len(out_numbers)
while (I less_than m and j less_than n):
    if (in_numbers[i] less_than out_numbers[j])
        currentoverlap equals currentoverlap + 1
        maxoverlap  equals max(maxoverlap, currentoverlap)
        i equals i + 1
    else:
        currentoverlap equals currentoverlap - 1
        j = j + 1


print maxoverlap
```

is there any idea, suggested readings e.t.c?

Comment: Did you try to implement this in Python? Does it work?

Comment: I do not understand what overlaps we are talking about since in the sample dataset above there is none. The stop of line `i` should be bigger than the start of line `i+1` to have an overlap. They are equal here.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis It was a type mistake thanks.

Comment: @Full Name yes it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum overlapping range is maybe (quase surely) not a whole tuple (start, stop) of input data.

So I'd transform you all your tuple (start, stop) in range containing all the range between start and stop:

```
(4556745,  4556749) → range(4556745, 4556749)
```

and then I'll process them to count the occurrence of each number (in a dict for exemple).

```
for range in ranges:
    for number in range:
        d.setdefault(num, 0)
        d[num]+=1
```

then you can get what ever you want. To get the max occurring numbers (what you call "maximum intersection") and the number of intersections concerned, you can use something like [get keys by maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary).

Comment: Very helpful thoughts i will try to implement this.