# Python: how to get the max value of a specific group in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary) that to get the maximum dictionary value in I can do:

```
dict[max(dict, key=dict.get)]
```

My dictionary looks like this:
    {article_title:number of how many different articles link to it}

example:
    {'10th century': 2, 'Poland' : 0, 'Mexico' : 11}

From group() I get a list of tuples (article_title, article object), example:
    [(Mexico, Mexico()), (Poland, Poland())]

For that group, I want to check what is the max value article_title may have.

But how do I find dictionary value of a specific group of keys? 
I'm really lost... I think what I wrote doesn't make sense:

```
dict = my dictionary
group_of_keys = group()  # returns specific list of tuples. The first term of the tuple is my key, the second is irrelevant
max_value = dict[max(dict[group_of_keys], key=dict.get)]
```

Help please!

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `group()`, as well as an example of the dictionary and your expected outputs please.

Comment: `dict = my dictionary` shadows the `dict` keyword, or at least it would do if it didn't contain whitespace and therefore raise a `SyntaxError`

Comment: I added an example of what the dictionary and group() output should look like.

Comment: @Bun if you convert your group to just having the keys of the dictionary , I.e. 'poland', 'mexico', then I think my answer works

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming `group()` returns a `list of keys`. If so you can get the values of those keys and then find the max out of them.

```
max(map(dict.get, groups()))
```

**EDIT:** As you clarified that `group()` returns a tuple of `(article_title, article_object)` and you want `article_title` as key what we can do is get the values of those keys as `dict.get(title) for title, article in group()` and then find the max among those values. So, the answer to your question is:

```
max(dict.get(title) for title, article in group())
```

Small note: `dict` is not a good name for a variable since it shadows python's reserved keyword `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

> By group I assume you mean a subset of your keys

```
my_dict = {} # your dictionary
group = get_group(my_dict)
# since your group returns tuples of (key, something else)
group = [ i[0] for i in group ]
max_group_key = max(group, my_dict.get)
max_group_value = my_dict[max_group_key]
```

Just for clarity, I'm taking a dictionary of month to temperatures.
`max_key` would tell me the month that had the highest temperature.
`max_group_key` would tell me the month within that group that had the highest temperature.

```
temperature = {
    "jan": 17, "feb": 18, "mar": 19, "apr": 24, "may": 26, 
    "jun": 25, "jul": 22, "aug": 21, "sep": 20, "oct": 20,
    "nov": 18, "dec": 15
}

# hottest month
max_key = max(temperature, key=temperature.get)
max_val = temperature[max_key]

print("hottest month: {0}, temperature: {1}".format(max_key, max_val))

# only for a few months
group = [ ("jan", "foo"), ("feb", "bar"), ("jun", "baz") ]
group = [ i[0] for i in group ]
max_group_key = max(group, key=temperature.get)
max_group_val = temperature[max_group_key]

print("hottest month: {0}, temperature: {1}".format(max_group_key, max_group_val))
```