# Python-Read marks from a text file and display the highest marks with the corresponding name

Tags: python

I want to write a program to read marks of 3 subjects from a file and display the highest mark of each subject with the corresponding name. so far I was able to write the program to get the highest marks but I couldn't develop it to display the corresponding name with it.

and here's my code:

```
def mymax(m):
    m.sort()
    mx=m[-1]
    return mx
s1=s2=s3=[]
rfile=open("marks.txt","r")
record=rfile.readline()
while record!="":
     data=record.strip("\n").split(",")
     x=int(data[1])
     y=int(data[2])
     z=int(data[3])
     s1=s1+[x]
     s2=s2+[y]
     s3=s3+[z]
     record=rfile.readline()
print("Highest marks of subject 1:",mymax(s1))
print("Highest marks of subject 2:",mymax(s2))
print("Highest marks of subject 3:",mymax(s3))
rfile.close()
```

The output I want is:
Highest marks of subject 1: marks,name
Highest marks of subject 2: marks,name
Highest marks of subject 3: marks,name

Comment: It would help to show a sample test file and its format. Is it `name,score1,score2,score3`?

Comment: no the output must be the highest marks of each subject and the corresponding name.

Comment: So you want us to write our own test files?

Answer (score 0):

Given your file format, you will have an easier time using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open('marks.txt') as f:
    subjects = 1, 2, 3  # specify subject columns
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)  # e.g. row: ['name_x', '3', '4', '5']
    # for each subject, zip the grades with their corresponding name
    named_grades = [[(int(r[i]), r[0]) for r in rows] for i in subjects]
    for i, s in enumerate(subjects):
        # feed max the (grade, name) pairs for each subject
        print("Highest marks of subject {}: {}, {}".format(s, *max(named_grades[i])))
```

For a file like

```
name1,2,7,1
name2,1,3,4
name3,6,6,2
name4,5,3,4
name5,3,2,5
name6,2,3,4
```

the output will be:

```
Highest marks of subject 1: 6, name3
Highest marks of subject 2: 7, name1
Highest marks of subject 3: 5, name5
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way of doing this is using python dictionary instead of a list in your code.here `s1=s2=s3=[]`.

`s1=s2=s3=[]`is a logical error because all lists point to a same list. hence all 3 list will have the same values/elements in their list.

And dictionary elements instead of just an int
, here

```
x=int(data[1])
y=int(data[2])
z=int(data[3])
```

So its basically a dictionary for each subject with names as keys(**Assuming names are unique**) and marks for corresponding subjects as values.
Accordingly small changes have to be made in your `mymax` function. you can Import `operator.itemgetter` to find the max of a dictionary based on specified columns.[Sorting dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value%22Sort%20dictionary%22),[finding Max value in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

So, the modified code would be

```
import operator
def mymax(m):
    sorted_m = sorted(m.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return sorted_m[-1]
s1={}
s2={}
s3={}
rfile=open("marks.txt","r")
record=rfile.readline()
while record!="":
     data=record.strip("\n").split(",")
     '''x=int(data[1])
     y=int(data[2])
     z=int(data[3])''' #not needed
     s1[data[0]]=int(data[1])
     s2[data[0]]=int(data[2])
     s3[data[0]]=int(data[3])
     record=rfile.readline()
print("Highest marks of subject 1:",mymax(s1))
print("Highest marks of subject 2:",mymax(s2))
print("Highest marks of subject 3:",mymax(s3))
rfile.close()
```

modify how you want to print the values according to your format.