# Getting the key and value for the largest by value of a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary of cities with their associated longitudes and latitudes:

```
CityCoords = {
'Denvor': {'lat': 9, 'lon': 8.5},
'Chicago': {'lat': 12.0, 'lon': 10.2},
'Frisco': {'lat': 10, 'lon': 9.5},
'Boston': {'lat': 11.5, 'lon': 11.0},
}
```

How do I obtain the name of the cities with the highest latitude and lowest longitude?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to `max()` or `min()` to define an appropriate key, e.g.:

```
In [1]:
CityCoords = {'Denvor': {'lat': 9, 'lon': 8.5}, 
              'Chicago': {'lat': 12.0, 'lon': 10.2},
              'Frisco': {'lat': 10, 'lon': 9.5},
              'Boston': {'lat': 11.5, 'lon': 11.0}}
max(CityCoords, key=lambda k: CityCoords[k]['lat'])

Out[1]:
'Chicago'

In [2]:
min(CityCoords, key=lambda k: CityCoords[k]['lon'])

Out[2]:
'Denver'
```

If you need the maximum distance between `lat`, `lon` then you could use

```
In [3]:
max(CityCoords, key=lambda k: CityCoords[k]['lat'] - CityCoords[k]['lon'])

Out[3]:
'Chicago'
```