# finding the keys of all the largest values in python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

if I have a dictionary

```
x ={0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 4}
```

how do i get the keys of all the largest values

In this case they would be 1 and 5 .

Not a duplicate question. looking to find all the keys and not just the one.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: I did. but that is to find the largest. so it only returns 1 and not 5.

Comment: Non trivial case here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

```
x ={0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 4}

maximum = max(x.values())
keys = [key for key, value in x.items() if value == maximum]
print(keys)  # => [1, 5]
```

Comment: This is much less convoluted than my answer.

Comment: The only recommendation I have is to unpack the tuple in the comprehension for the sake of readability: `[key for key, value in x.items() if value == maximum]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a class in [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that does exactly what you want. It provides the exact functionality you require via it's [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
from collections import counter
maxes = Counter(x).most_common(2)
print([x[0] for x in maxes])
```

```
[1, 5]
```

Now this is probably not exactly what you want because I hard coded in the number 2. You can get this by using another `Counter` on the values of your dictionary!

```
x = Counter(x) # This preserves x: just makes it a subclass of dict
max_count = Counter(x.values())[x.most_common(1)[0][1]]
maxes = x.most_common(max_count)
maxes = [x[0] for x in maxes]
```

Here, I compute the number of times that the most common value occurs by counting all the different values, and then checking the maximum one using `x.most_common(1)[0][1]`.

Please do not select this answer. @BrightOne has the right answer. This is just a thing I did to see if I could avoid using anything but Counters. It is not actually a good idea.