# define a function for max score from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on the following, I created a dictionary object as follows and I need to define 3 different functions. A function for maxScore, a function for minScore, and function for average as well as print all 3.

My dictionary object code is as follows

```
scores = {}
scores['Andy'] = 78
scores['Bill'] = 82
scores['Cindy'] = 94
scores['Dave'] = 77
scores['Emily'] = 82
scores['Frank'] = 94
scores['Gene'] = 87
```

I can't seem to define the function(s) correctly for it to print the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: @AGNGazer Without it (or something similar), `scores['Andy'] = 78` will raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 5):

use `min()` and `max` :

```
>>> scores = {}
>>> scores['Andy'] = 78
>>> scores['Bill'] = 82
>>> scores['Cindy'] = 94
>>> scores['Dave'] = 77
>>> scores['Emily'] = 82
>>> scores['Frank'] = 94
>>> scores['Gene'] = 87

>>> max(scores, key=scores.get)
'Frank'
>>> min(scores, key=scores.get)
'Dave'
```

and for the average :

```
>>> sum(scores[i] for i in scores)/len(scores)
84
```

Answer (score 1):

For max:

```
def max_val(scores):
    return max(scores.values())
```

min

```
def min_val(scores):
    return min(scores.values())
```

and avg

```
    def avg_val(scores):
        return sum(scores.values())/len(scores)
```

Comment: If `min` and `max` are both just returning a value, you don't need to know the key. Just use `max(scores.values())`. (Also, you've inadvertently created an infinite recursion situation by re-using `min` and `max` as your function names.)

Comment: You're completely right. That's embarrassing. Edited answer to reflect changes.

Comment: Ditto for `avg_val`; you don't need the key. You don't need the loop, either: `sum(scores.values())` gets the sum. Although, it is debatable which is better: compute a running calculation of the length while iterating, or iterate twice implicitly (in `sum` and `len`).

Comment: I noticed that as well and fixed it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I am just starting out and this one tripped me up.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to accept someone's answer so people know the question is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Max Score:

```
def maxScore(scDict):
  max = scDict[0]
  for i in scDict:
    if scDict[i]>max:
      max=scDict[i]
  return max
```

Min Score:

```
def minScore(scDict):
  min = scDict[0]
  for i in scDict:
    if scDict[i]<max:
      min=scDict[i]
  return min
```

Avg Score:

```
def avgScore(scDict):
  avg = 0. # python 2
  for i in scDict:
    avg+=scDict[i]
  return avg/len(scDict)
```

You can also use something like `sys.maxsize` in case of minScore (Py 3.0) if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
best_scores = sorted(scores, key=scores.get, reverse=True)
maxScore = scores[best_scores[0]]
minScore = scores[best_scores[-1]]
average =  sum(scores.values())/len(scores.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(scores.items(), cmp=lambda x, y: x[1] - y[1])
```