# Find the key for the latest date value represented as string

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, max

How do I find the key for the latest date value of a dictionary where the dates are represented as strings?

I tried using `max(date, key=date.get)` as in [*Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280156/7851470), but it returns wrong results:

```
date = {"sale_date": "2018-02-17 20:11:37.017298",
        "buy_date": "2018-02-2 20:11:37.017298"}

latest = max(date, key=date.get)
```

This returns `"buy_date"` but clearly the result should be `"sale_date"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
> date={"sale_date":"2018-02-17 20:11:37.017298","buy_date":"2018-02-1 20:11:37.017298"}
> sorted([(value,key) for key,value in date.items()], key=lambda x:x[1])[0][1]
'sale_date'
```

by adding `reversed=True` to the `sorted` function, you can have it reversed.

Comment: whatever the condition is this code always gives me 'sale_date'

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava I updated my answer, there was a key mismatch there. it gave you the earliest always, now it returns the latest.

Comment: [datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 18, 8, 6, 18, 924753), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 18, 8, 6, 10, 795445)]

Comment: i found my datetime object like this

Comment: get `max` or `min` from that.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in `str` format you can change it to date format, date is comparable So you can take the `max` to get latest date, Also for finding key with value in python you can try the below method:

```
dt={"sale_date":"2018-02-17 20:11:37.017298",
      "buy_date":"2018-02-1 20:11:37.017298" }
l = [datetime.datetime.strptime(j, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for j in dt.values()]
for k,v in dt.items():
    if v == str(max(l)):
        print(k)
```

Avoid  giving variables name like date, string... etc

Comment: successfully runs on local but when i upload it to server this gives me    strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime

Comment: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime

Comment: So just try only with `l = [ j for j in dt.values()]`  this instead of strptime

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava what is error with posted code in your question , its working fine when I'am trying

Comment: @ Vikas Damodar what ever the condition is this always gives me "sale_date"

Comment: [datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 18, 8, 6, 18, 924753), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 18, 8, 6, 10, 795445)]
 i found my datetime object like this

Comment: You don't need to keep the datetimes in an intermediate list. You could just use a custom key function like: `max(my_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(date[x], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))`