# List of tuples that have race times. Need to list the name and time of the winner for each race

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

I'm doing my work on Python 3. Need help with putting together the logic for knowing who won the races.

```
results_2002 = [("John Williams", "USA", 5.5),("Jim Newsom",
"Canada", 6.1), ("Paul Smith", "Netherlands", 5.3)

results_2004 = [("Simon Dent", "Canada", 6.2),("Stan Doe", "USA",
6.1), ("Paul Smith", "Netherlands", 5.4)

def find_winner(results):

    #I need help with the logic of figure out who won these two races

    return

find_winner(results_2002)
find_winner(results_2004)
```

I've been trying to do a reverse sorted for the tuples and printing out the first racer it gives from that but I am getting errors or it will only list the first time put into the list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: One way to approach your assignment: create a dictionary and find key with highest value: https://stackoverflow.com/q/268272/8881141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) (or [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) depending on your criteria for winning) with a `key` that specifies which value to consider for determining max (or min):

```
def find_winner(results):
    return max(results, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

**Output**

```
print(find_winner(results_2002)) # ('Jim Newsom', 'Canada', 6.1)
print(find_winner(results_2004)) # ('Simon Dent', 'Canada', 6.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [built-in method : sorted](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) to sort your list according to a certain key.

```
unsorted_list = [("John Williams", "USA", 5.5),("Jim Newsom","Canada", 6.1), ("Paul Smith", "Netherlands", 5.3)]

# sort with regards to 3d entry of the tuple
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x:x[2]) #
print(sorted_list)
```

> Output:
>
> [('Paul Smith', 'Netherlands', 5.3),
>    ('John Williams', 'USA', 5.5),
>    ('Jim Newsom', 'Canada', 6.1)]

The winner is the first element or the last element of the list. I guess it's the first if the integers in your tuple are timings.

```
def first_place(results):
  """ return the first place if any."""

  sorted_results = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x:x[2])
  return next(iter(sorted_results), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results_2002 = [("John Williams", "USA", 5.5),("Jim Newsom",
"Canada", 6.1), ("Paul Smith", "Netherlands", 5.3)]

results_2004 = [("Simon Dent", "Canada", 6.2),("Stan Doe", "USA",
6.1), ("Paul Smith", "Netherlands", 5.4)]

def find_winner(results):

    return [j for j in results if j[2] == max([i[2] for i in results])] 

print(*find_winner(results_2002))
print(*find_winner(results_2004))
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
('Jim Newsom', 'Canada', 6.1)
('Simon Dent', 'Canada', 6.2)
```

**NOTE:** I took *maximum* as a ***winner*** if you want minimum change `max` to `min`.