# How to get value from nested data

Tags: python-3.x

I want maximum scorer from this complicated data, but it shows error, maybe I am doing something wrong here.

```
students = {
    'harshit':{'score':90, 'age':22},
    'Mohit':{'score':79, 'age':20},
    'Rohit':{'score':99, 'age':29}
}

print((max(students , key= lambda item: item.get('score'))))
```

> I expected the output : Rohit
>   but here I got an error `cox they're saying item is a string` but for my case it is also a key

Comment: Check out [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: @TheGamer007 I don't think it's dup as OP wants to find max within nested dict.

Comment: Yeah but i have more complicated dictionary but wait now i'm trying ,,,, maybe i'll get my solution now because i'm operating my 'item' but they are accessing direct their root dictionary so wait i'm trying sir

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar yeah, retracted the flag. Thanks

Comment: i've Done ..Thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh I Got it!! Now i'm accessing my key from main dictionary then inside elements

```
students = {
    'harshit':{'score':9, 'age':22},
    'Mohit':{'score':9, 'age':20},
    'Rohit':{'score':9, 'age':29}
}
print((max(students , key= lambda item: students[item]['score'])))
```

Answer (score 3):

you probably want this -

```
students = {
    'harshit':{'score':90, 'age':22},
    'Mohit':{'score':79, 'age':20},
    'Rohit':{'score':99, 'age':29}
}

print((max(students , key= lambda item: students[item].get('score'))))
```

By lambda you are specifying the key. So `students[item]` to iterate over the `students` and then `get('score')` to get score for a particular entry.

Comment: i've also done this but i was posting my answer ,,, but you are also correct brother .. Thanku so much Brother