# Get the key with the biggest score in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value

I'd like to know if you know other/better way (without max method) to get a key with the biggest score in a dictionary ? :

```
report_card = {'french' : 14,
            'english' : 12,
            'math' : 16,
            'chemistry' : 19,
            'sport' : 14}
max = 0

for subject, score in report_card.items():
    if max < report_card[subject]:
        max = report_card[subject]

for subject, score in report_card.items():
    if max == report_card[subject]:
        print(f"The subject with the highest score is {subject} with {score} points")
```

Comment: And why without the max function?

Comment: keeping the running max which you are doing is perhaps the best way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary). There are at least 4 or 5 answers that don't use `max` on this thread.

Comment: I didn't want use 'max' just for training my logic and for fun (I start programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat simpler, but please, the max function is there for a reason.

```
report_card = {'french' : 14,
            'english' : 12,
            'math' : 16,
            'chemistry' : 19,
            'sport' : 14}
max = 0
max_s = ""

for subject, score in report_card.items():
    if max < score:
        max = score
        max_s = subject

print(f"The subject with the highest score is {max_s} with {max} points")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
max(report_card.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

dict.items() return all values as pairs. max returns maximum value of an iterable. key keyword allows you to pass function, that produces value for each item to compare for maximum. max function will return one of values produced by report_card.items() (not value produced by key functor), so you need [0] to get key from it.