# How to find the max of key which has the max of key value product

Tags: python, dictionary

Find the max of the key which is having the product max of key and value

I got the output, I am in search of best solution

```
a = [3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
c = set(a)
counts = {}
for i in a:
    if i in counts:
        counts[i] += 1
    else:
        counts[i] =1
#counts
t = [k*v for k,v in counts.items()]
max_index = t.index(max(t))
list(c)[max_index]
```

> > 6

NO error, how to optimize the code. need list comprehension at the position

for[k*v for k,v in counts.items()]. Can i add map function to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: @hs - Mous is looking for the max(Key*Value) in his dict ...

Comment: Are you certain your code is doing what you expect it to do? You are calculating the index of `max(t)` in `t` and then apply it to the set of unique items in `a` (which, AFAIK does not have a guaranteed order anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use `collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or [`collections.defaultdict` with `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do the counting for you (both are faster then your -valid- solution).

To get the maximum value [use `sorted()`- see sorting overview](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with an appropriate `key` function:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
c = Counter(a)

m = sorted(c.items(),key= lambda x: x[0]*x[1], reverse = True)
print(m)
```

Prints

```
[(6, 3), (7, 2), (5, 2), (4, 1), (3, 1)]
```

so `m[0][0]` would be your result of `6`.

`max(...)` can also use the same key function, if you are only interested in the maximal value.

---

Defaultdict version (more lines then Counter):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7]
c = defaultdict(int)
for num in a:
    c[num] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can use a map to get the "t" list

```
def function(item):
    return item[0]*item[1]
t = list(map(function, counts.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dictionary so the values are already multiplied by the keys. Then you can use one of the solutions in [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary) to find the keys with the maximum value.

```
for i in a:
    if i in counts:
        counts[i] += i
    else:
        counts[i] = i
```