# How to get a key with highest value from a dictionary that is created from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a string that is in the format of `k1=v1,k2=v2` and so on. I want to return that `k` which has highest `v`.

I am trying to run below code but it does not seem to work -

```
s1 = "0=0.0,1=4.097520999795124e-05,2=0.0007278731184387373,3=0.339028551210803,4=0.33231086508575525,5=0.32789173537500504"
stats = dict(map(lambda x: x.split('='), s1.split(',')))
x = max(stats, key=stats.get)
print(x)
```

This prints `1` whereas the expected output is `3`.

Comment: remember your keys are strings (what str.split is going to return) not integers.  12 < 2 in string ordering.

Comment: Duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `max`, with a key to consider only the second value in the `key`/`value` tuples. Also note that the `values` must be cast to `float`, since otherwise element's comparisson will be lexicographical:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max_val = max(((k,float(v)) for k,v in stats.items()), key=itemgetter(1))
print(max_val)
# ('3', 0.339028551210803)

print(max_val[0])
# 3
```