# Finding maximum value in a dictionary Python

Tags: python-3.x

the input I have given is

- BatmanA,14
- BatmanB,199
- BatmanC,74
- BatmanD,15
- BatmanE,9

and the output i expect is the highest value and i get something else this is my code below i have tried other methods too pls help thanks.

```
N = int(input("Enter the number of batsman : "))

d = {}

for i in range(0,N):
    batsman = input("enter the batsman values " ).split(',')
    d[batsman[0]] = batsman[1]
v = list(d.values())
k = list(d.keys())
print(k[v.index(max(v))])
```

Comment: what result do you get? one issue is probably that the value is currently a string, so the `max` function does behave as you would expect if the values where numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
d[max(d, key=d.get)]
```

See [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary) for more discussion.