# How to pull the key and value of an item with the maximum value out of a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max

The following code creates a dictionary of email addresses and how frequently each email appears.  What is the best way to pull out the key and value for the email with the max frequency?

```
fname = input("Enter file:")
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:')
    exit()
counts = dict() 
for line in fhand:  
    if line.startswith('From:'):
         words = line.split(' ', 1)[1]
         words = words.rstrip('\n')

         counts[words] = counts.get(words,0)+1

print(counts)
```

Comment: BTW, [a bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341)

Comment: BTW use context for more clean code

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

```
import operator
max(counts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Or you can define two variables

```
max_count = 0
frequent = None
```

and append the following to the if clause

```
if counts[words] > max_count
    max_count = counts[words] 
    frequent = words
```

At the end `frequent` would contain most frequent email (or `None` if there is no email in file).

Comment: For Python 3, use `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

you can get both the key and value using

```
sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-1]
```

or

```
sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the key and value in a comprehension and use max() normally:

```
count,word = max(c,w for w,c in counts.items())
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead, which has a [`most_common` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

```
from collections import Counter

# Ignoring file opening code since it's irrelevant...

counts = Counter()
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('From:'):
         email_addr = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ', 1)[1]
         counts[email_addr] += 1

print(counts.most_common(1))
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
counts = Counter(
    line.rstrip('\n').split(' ', 1)[1]
    for line in fhand
    if line.startswith('From:')
    )
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... This does work. Any feedback appreciated.