# Find out max value from a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and I am having a dict. I would like to find out the maximum valued fields from the dict like for **index 0 and 1** there is a **common value in the dict i.e 1**. So I would like to identify the max value which is **0.8** and to be pointed out.

```
 0: ['1', 'Metrolink', 0.7054569125175476],
 1: ['1', 'Toronto', 0.8],
```

Like wise I would like to do the same for all other values.

This is my complete dict.

```
 d={
 0: ['1', 'Metrolink', 0.7054569125175476],
 1: ['1', 'Toronto', 0.8],
 4: ['2', 'Residence Inn Bentonville', 0.721284806728363],
 5: ['2', 'Bentonville, Arkansas', 0.8],
 7: ['2', 'Rogers', 0.5609406232833862],
 8: ['2', 'Toronto', 0.8],
 10: ['2', 'Arkansas', 0.8871413469314575],
 12: ['2', 'CA', 0.5339972972869873],
 14: ['3', 'Toronto', 0.8],
 19: ['3', 'ik', 0.555569052696228],
 21: ['4', 'DL', 0.47785162925720215],
 22: ['4', 'MS', 0.5182732939720154],
 23: ['4', 'Nashville International Airport', 0.8],
 27: ['4', 'Turkey', 0.8],
 30: ['5', 'Hebron, Kentucky', 0.8],
 32: ['5', 'OAK PARK', 0.6157999038696289],
 35: ['5', 'USA', 0.5055036544799805],
 36: ['5', 'Tennessee', 0.5752009153366089],
 37: ['5', 'Recov', 0.6585434675216675],
 38: ['5', 'County (United States)', 0.8],
 40: ['6', 'SFO', 0.6019220948219299],
 42: ['6', 'Ontario', 0.8],
 45: ['7', 'United States', 0.6973987221717834],
 47: ['7', 'Buckingham Gate', 0.8],
 48: ['7', 'London', 0.9545853137969971],
 53: ['8', 'Phoenix, Arizona', 0.8],
 55: ['8', 'STE', 0.5046005249023438],
 56: ['8', 'TULSA', 0.7144339680671692],
 58: ['8', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', 0.8454625606536865],
 60: ['9', 'RDU', 0.6373313069343567],
 61: ['9', 'Raleigh–Durham International Airport', 0.8],
 65: ['9', 'Piauí', 0.8],
 69: ['9', 'CAR', 0.6243148446083069],
 71: ['10', 'MONMOUTH JUNCTION', 0.7259661555290222],
 72: ['10', 'New Jersey', 0.8],
 76: ['10', 'PVK', 0.6593300104141235],
 79: ['10', 'TWW', 0.6495188474655151],
 81: ['10', 'Morrisville, Bucks County, Pennsylvania', 0.8],
 84: ['10', 'United States', 0.8],
 88: ['10', 'New Brunswick, New Jersey', 0.8]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is very effective tool for handling tabular data like this. You could create a pandas DataFrame from the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
df.columns = ('group', 'place', 'value')
```

and then just print out the maximum values

```py
df[df['value'] == df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('max')]
```

which gives

```py
Out[41]:
   group                                    place     value
1      1                                  Toronto       0.8
10     2                                 Arkansas  0.887141
14     3                                  Toronto       0.8
23     4          Nashville International Airport       0.8
27     4                                   Turkey       0.8
30     5                         Hebron, Kentucky       0.8
38     5                   County (United States)       0.8
42     6                                  Ontario       0.8
48     7                                   London  0.954585
58     8                 UNITED STATES OF AMERICA  0.845463
61     9      RaleighDurham International Airport       0.8
65     9                                    Piauí       0.8
72    10                               New Jersey       0.8
81    10  Morrisville, Bucks County, Pennsylvania       0.8
84    10                            United States       0.8
88    10                New Brunswick, New Jersey       0.8
```

If you want to get the output in the original format, you can use [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```py
In [47]: df[df['value'] == df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('max')].T.to_dict(orient='list')
Out[47]:
{1: ['1', 'Toronto', 0.8],
 10: ['2', 'Arkansas', 0.8871413469314575],
 14: ['3', 'Toronto', 0.8],
 23: ['4', 'Nashville International Airport', 0.8],
 27: ['4', 'Turkey', 0.8],
 30: ['5', 'Hebron, Kentucky', 0.8],
 38: ['5', 'County (United States)', 0.8],
 42: ['6', 'Ontario', 0.8],
 48: ['7', 'London', 0.9545853137969971],
 58: ['8', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', 0.8454625606536865],
 61: ['9', 'RaleighDurham International Airport', 0.8],
 65: ['9', 'Piauí', 0.8],
 72: ['10', 'New Jersey', 0.8],
 81: ['10', 'Morrisville, Bucks County, Pennsylvania', 0.8],
 84: ['10', 'United States', 0.8],
 88: ['10', 'New Brunswick, New Jersey', 0.8]}
```

#### Short explanation

- Pandas dataframes can be created using dictionaries as arguments. The values should be lists. The `.T` takes just transpose of the table.
- The `df.groupby('group')['value']` returns a SeriesGroupBy object, which behaves very much like a regular pandas.Series object. With that we can calculate the maximum `value` for each `group`, using the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method.
- The `df['value'] == df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('max')` creates a boolean mask for selecting the maximum rows by `df[mask]`.

Comment: Good solution, can also use `transform(max)` instead of `transform('max')`

Comment: Oh yeah, did not think about the `max()` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get the maximum value across each sub-key (the first item of each entry's value). To do that, you can use this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

max_values = defaultdict(lambda: (float('-inf'), None))

for label, text, value in d.values():
    max_values[label] = max(max_values[label], (value, text))
```

Using `defaultdict` here with a default value of `(float('-inf'), None)` allows us to compare new max values to old new values without having to check if a max value was recorded in the first place.

`max_values` ends up as:

```
{
    '1': (0.8, 'Toronto'), 
    '2': (0.8871413469314575, 'Arkansas'), 
    '3': (0.8, 'Toronto'), 
    '4': (0.8, 'Turkey'), 
    '5': (0.8, 'Hebron, Kentucky'),
    '6': (0.8, 'Ontario'), 
    '7': (0.9545853137969971, 'London'), 
    '8': (0.8454625606536865, 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA'),
    '9': (0.8, 'Raleigh–Durham International Airport'), 
    '10': (0.8, 'United States')
}
```

Comment: this works. but i would like to get the text like Metrolink, Toronto etc having the max values in the max_values.

Comment: @Binny Updated answer to include the text, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Some groups (4, 5, 8, 10) have multiple entries that have equally high value; this method will not list _all_ the entries with the maximum value within the group.

Comment: can i get the text like Toronto,London etc only from the results  @Mario Ishac

Answer (score 0):

you could get sorted dictionary with following code:

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv:(int(kv[1][0]), kv[1][2])))
```

if you want to sort based on first element and second element, you cloud ues:

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv:(int(kv[1][0]), kv[1][1])))
```