# The largest value with its key from the following dictionary python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

Input is: `book_shop = {'sci fi': 12, 'mystery': 15, 'horror': 8, 'mythology': 10, 'young_adult': 4, 'adventure':14}`

Output has to be: `The highest selling book genre is mystery and the number of books sold are 15`

**Need to solve this without using max function.**

I've tried this:

```
book_shop = {'sci fi': 12, 'mystery': 15, 'horror': 8, 'mythology': 10, 'young_adult': 4, 'adventure':14}
largest = 0

for key, value in book_shop.items():
    if largest in book_shop.values():
        largest = book_shop.values()
        key = book_shop.keys()
        
print("The highest selling book genre is ", key, " and the number of books sold are ", largest)
```

Output came: `The highest selling book genre is  adventure  and the number of books sold are  0`

What to do?

Comment: What have you tried on your side before you asked? What problems did you stumble upon? Please share your code!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: Yes. Just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the key with max value using :

```
max_key = max(book_shop,key=book_shop.get)

print("The highest selling book genre is ", max_key, " and the no of books sold are ",book_shop.get(max_key))
```

Updated your code to get max value without max function. Basically you should compare the largest value with the value for that specific key.

```
In [193]: book_shop = {'sci fi': 12, 'mystery': 15, 'horror': 8, 'mythology': 10, 'young_adult': 4, 'adventure':14} 
     ...: largest = 0 
     ...: key1= "" 
     ...: for key, value in book_shop.items(): 
     ...:     #print("key ",key," value ",value) 
     ...:     if largest < int(book_shop.get(key)): 
     ...:         #print(True) 
     ...:         largest = value 
     ...:         key1 = key 
     ...:          
     ...: print("The highest selling book genre is ", key1, " and the number of books sold are ", largest)
```

Comment: Without using max function

Comment: added a solution without max function