# Sorting pandas value based on another dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df_1` like this:

```
A                      

apple, iphone, android
facebook, apple
macbook, laptop
firestick, hulu, netflix
android, laptop
laptop
```

And `df_2` like this:

```
A           B

apple       1
macbook     2
facebook    3
firestick   4
hulu        5
netflix     6
android     7
laptop      8
```

I am trying to extract a single word from `A` column of `df_1` that has the lowest value in column `B` from `df_2` like so:

```
A                               B_new

apple, iphone, android          apple
facebook, apple                 apple
macbook, laptop                 macbook
hulu, netflix, firestick        firesick
laptop, android                 android                 
laptop                          laptop
```

I assume I could sort each value of `df_1` column `A` based on the values of `B` in `df_2`. Or create a function that takes in a single `A` value from `df_1` and returns `str` with the smallest number in `B` from `df_2`. But as the data is quite big I assume using `apply` is not very efficient. Is there a neat *Pandas* way of doing such task?

Comment: So neither of your data frames are indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionary and matching values if exist, then get maximal value else missing value:

```
d = df_2.set_index('A')['B'].to_dict()

def f(x):
    d1 = {y:d[y] for y in x.split(', ') if y in d}
    return min(d1, key=d1.get)  if len(d1) > 1 else np.nan
```

Or:

```
import operator

def f(x):
    d1 = {y:d[y] for y in x.split(', ') if y in d}
    return min(d1.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] if len(d1) > 1 else np.nan
```

---

```
df_1['new'] = df_1['A'].apply(f)
print (df_1)
                          A        new
0    apple, iphone, android      apple
1           facebook, apple      apple
2           macbook, laptop    macbook
3  firestick, hulu, netflix  firestick
4           android, laptop    android
5                    laptop     laptop
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran `timeit` the first function runs `138 ms ± 2.74 ms per loop` while the other `156 ms ± 2.29 ms per loop`.  Any recommendations when I should use the `operator` module?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Hard question, I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268285/2901002) solution.

Answer (score 1):

@jezrael's solution is cleaner, and should be faster, since we are dealing with strings; the solution below is an alternative:

Iterate to get the individual entries:

```
values = [[value.strip() for value in entry.split(",")] 
          for entry in df1.A.__iter__()]
values

[['apple', 'iphone', 'android'],
 ['facebook', 'apple'],
 ['macbook', 'laptop'],
 ['firestick', 'hulu', 'netflix'],
 ['android', 'laptop'],
 ['laptop']]
```

Get the minimum, which in this case will be the first True:

```
values = [df2.loc[df2.A.isin(value), "B"].idxmin() 
          for value in values]
values
[0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 7]
```

Select the values and assign to the new column:

```
df1.loc[:, 'B_new'] = df2.iloc[values, 0]


       A                           B_new
0   apple, iphone, android         apple
1   facebook, apple                apple
2   macbook, laptop               macbook
3   firestick, hulu, netflix    firestick
4   android, laptop              android
5   laptop                        laptop
```

Comment: `df1['B_new'] = df2.iloc[values, 0]` ?

Comment: Yes, it takes a while but does the job, thanks for another perspective on this problem.

Comment: yea, more often than not, string functions are faster in plain python than Pandas

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest either, but I like this other way of thinking about this.

You could use the method str.get_dummies, perform column wise multiplications and take the idxmin :

```
ab_dict = df_2.set_index("A")["B"].to_dict()
df_1["B"] = df_1["A"].str.get_dummies(", ")
        .apply(lambda c: c.replace(0, np.nan)*ab_dict.get(c.name, np.nan))
        .idxmin(axis=1)
```