# How to access a key through its value in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
banks = {
    "National Bank of Canada" : "327",
    "Toronto-Dominion Bank" : "302", 
    "Royal Bank of Canada" : "173", 
    "Wells Fargo" : "273", 
    "Goldman Sachs" : "87", 
    "Morgan Stanley" : "72", 
    "Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce" : "83",
    "TD Bank" : "108", 
    "Bank of Montreal" : "67", 
    "Capital One" : "47", 
    "FNB Corporation" : "4", 
    "Laurentian Bank of Canada" : "3", 
    "Ally Financial" : "12",
    "Montreal Trust Company" : "145",
    "Canadian Western Bank" : ".97"
}



for value in banks.values():
    count += 1
    total_mkt_cap += float(value)
    total =+ count
    if float(value) > float(largest):
        largest = value
```

The variable `largest` is now the value `327`, but I would like `largest` to be the key which is `"National Bank of Canada"`, not the value, any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `largest` contains the largest value, you can find the key associated with it by iterating over the dictionary `(key, value)`:

```py
for key, value in banks.items():
    if value == largest:
        desired_key = key
        break

print(desired_key)
```

Keep in mind that it will give you the first key associated with this value.

### Alternative solution

Alternatively, you can use the following logic that uses `operator.itemgetter` and `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import operator
import ast

banks = {key: ast.literal_eval(value) for key, value in banks.items()}
print(max(banks.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
```

The previous code will give you the key of the highest value once it has been converted to either an int or a float.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you! First time actually asking my own question on stackoverflow and you guys answered within minutes.

I didn't realise you could iterate over the key and value in the same loop, so that solved it for me, much appreciated

Comment: @TomWeekes, I am glad my answer helped you. If you do not mind, could you please validate my answer?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf I clicked the tick next to your answer now it is green, is that what you meant?

Comment: Your syntax seems not correct, what if you use `elif float(value) >= 10 and float(value) < 300`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd give something like below a try.

```
banks = {
    "National Bank of Canada" : "327",
    "Toronto-Dominion Bank" : "302", 
}
#don't worry about this line. It just gets the largest value.
largest = str(max(map(int,banks.values())))
for bankName,id in banks.items():  # for name, age in dictionary.iteritems():  (for Python 2.x)
    if id == largest:
        largest = bankName
print(largest)
```

output

```
National Bank of Canada
```