# Return a key value-pair which value is the highest

Tags: python, dictionary, max, key-value

The dictionary:

```
sales_year = {"1998": 3124, "1999": 234, "2001": 7214, "2002": 789}
```

How can I return the **key-value pair** of which the value is the highest? In this case it should return:

```
("2001", 7214)
```

Is there any function like "max()" which is as simple as possible?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/280156/12693728

Answer (score 0):

Buddy Bob's homemade approach. Find max value, iterate through dicts keys, locate certain key.

```
sales_year = {"1998": 3124, "1999": 234, "2001": 7214, "2002": 789}
for k in sales_year.keys():
    if sales_year[k] == max(sales_year.values()):
        print(k,max(sales_year.values()))
        break
```