# How to get the key of dictionary whose value is greater?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the dictionary as shown below and I want to pick the key whose value is the maximum in dictionary

```
dictionary = {'george': 16, 'amber': 19 ,'leper':23}

Expected_Output: leper
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
max_key = max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
print(max_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may not be the best method to get the answer when it comes to time complexity**

```
dictionary = {'george': 16, 'amber': 19, 'leper': 23}

# Creating the list of values
values = [i for i in dictionary.values()]

# Creating the list of keys

keys = [i for i in dictionary.keys()]

# Declaring the g [greater value]

g = int

# iterating through the list to find the maximum value

for i in range(len(values)):
    try:
        temp_i = values[i+1]
    except IndexError:
        temp_i = values[i]
    for i in values:
        if temp_i > i:
            g = temp_i
        else:
            g = i

pos = values.index(g)
print(keys[pos])
```