# How to find the greatest value in the nested dictionary

Tags: python

There exists a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {'alpha':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}}
```

How to return a single list with one key inside which refers to the greatest value. If there are multiple occurrences of the greatest value then return a list with keys of similar value.

Comment: Could you write the desired output please?

Comment: You haven't show any attempt here, so it's not clear what you're stuck on. You presumably know how to iterate a dictionary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` to get the maximum value, and extract the keys that has that value:

```
max_value = max(my_dict['alpha'].values())
print([key for key, value in my_dict['alpha'].items() if value == max_value])
```