# How to get largest FLOAT value in dictionary for Python and return Key

Tags: python

```
dictFloat = {'1':110.25,'2':0.25,'3':50.50,'4':250.25}
```

I need to get the value 250.25 from the dictionary and get the key 4

Comment: Google is your friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work with floats

Answer (score 0):

If you get the dictionary items as tuples, and swap the order of the pair, you can rely on the built-in tuple collation rules, that will consider `(a1,b1) > (a2,b2)` if `a1 > a2`:

```
max((v,k) for k,v in dictFloat.items())
# (250.25, '4')
```