# how to set selection criteria in regex (how to set t the number of character in selection) in python

Tags: python, string, sorting, python-re

I am having a text file in which some binary numbers are there. I want to count number of occurrence of some digits/characters using pattern, and I want to sort it in descending order (till this point code working fine. but I want result should show only more than 7 characters. it means i can change in my selection pattern = r"(0+1+0+1+0+1+)" {<7}

```
import re
from collections import Counter



pattern = r"0+1+0+1+0+1+"

test_str = '0101010110110110110110110101010111011101110111101111010101111010111010101111011010101011011011011011011011'

cnt = Counter(re.findall(pattern, test_str))
print(cnt.most_common())


# result [('011011011', 2), ('010101', 1), ('0111011101111', 1), ('010111101', 1), ('0111101101', 1)]
```

result should be display only more than 8 character it no supposed to show ('010101', 1)

Comment: Have you googled about "sort a dict by values" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Counter` will do exactly the job.

```py
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter(re.findall(pattern, test_str))
print(cnt.most_common())  # [('110110', 3), ('110100', 2), ('101110', 2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to print the highest value you can do this:

```
print(max(cnt.items()))
```